# Truncate TreeForm to show only the top

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization, trees

For some expressions, `TreeForm` may grow very long. I'm only interested in the top levels of the expression. How can I get the tree form of only the first levels an expression?

For example: how to get the first levels of this expression in tree form?

```
Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5]
```

[image: TreeLevel of the above expression]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can use something like this:

```
ClearAll[showTopTree];
showTopTree[expr_, level_] :=
  Module[{myHold}, 
     SetAttributes[myHold, HoldAll];
     Function[code,
       TreeForm[Unevaluated@Unevaluated@code],
       HoldAll] @@
    (Hold[#] &@
      DeleteCases[MapAll[myHold, expr], _, {2*level, Infinity}] //.
           myHold[x__] :> x)];
```

Pretty ugly, but seems to work:

```
expr = Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5]
Manipulate[showTopTree[expr, n], {n, 1, Depth[expr], 1}]

GraphicsGrid[Partition[showTopTree[expr, #] & /@ Range[6], 3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the second argument of `TreeForm` to display and expression to a certain depth, so for your example you could do `TreeForm[Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5], 1]` (although the result isn't very pretty in this case)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Instead of using `TreeForm` you could also construct a graph of the expression using `ExpressionTreePlot` in the `` GraphUtilities` `` package and use that to extract the desired subtree.

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
exprTree[expr_] :=
 Module[{g, edges, labels},
  g = ExpressionTreePlot[expr, Top];
  edges = Rule @@@ Cases[g, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity][[1]];
  labels = Cases[g, Text[a_, b_] :> (b -> a[[1, 1]]), Infinity];
  {edges, labels}]

subTree[expr_, d_, pos_: Top] := Module[{edges, labels, sub},
  {edges, labels} = exprTree[expr];
  sub = NeighborhoodSubgraph[edges, 1, d];
  TreePlot[sub, pos, VertexRenderingFunction ->
    Function[{p, v}, 
     Text[Framed[Style[v /. labels, FontSize -> 10], 
       Background -> Lighter[Gray, .8]], p]]]]
```

Example:

```
subTree[Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5], 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, I've chosen the style of `VertexRenderingFunction` in the definition of `subTree` to mimic the style of `TreeForm` but you could choose you own style for displaying the vertex labels.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions seem a bit complicated. What about this one?

```
myTreeForm[expr_, dep_] := Map[Head, TreeForm[expr, dep], {dep + 1}];
a = Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5];

myTreeForm[a, 1]
myTreeForm[a, 2]
myTreeForm[a, 3]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[trimmedTree]
trimmedTree[expr_, level_, o : OptionsPattern[]] :=  Module[{
  g = GraphComputation`ExpressionGraph[expr, o, GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold" ], g2},
  g2 = SetProperty[g, VertexLabels -> (v_ :> 
     Placed[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels] , Center])];
  VertexDelete[g2, _?(GraphDistance[g2, 1, #] > level &)]]
```

**Examples:**

```
trimmedTree[{{{a, b}, c}, d}, #, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {1, 2, 3} // Row
```

[image]

```
trimmedTree[Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5], #, 
   VertexSize->{"Scaled", .14}, ImageSize -> #2]&@@@{{1, 250},{2, 300},{3, 300}} // Row
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the new-in-version-12.1 function [`ExpressionGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html) you can trim the expression tree using the second argument:

- `ExpressionGraph[expr, n]` gives the tree graph only down to level `n`.

***Example:***

```
expr = Nest[1/(1 + #) (1 - #) &, w, 5];

ExpressionGraph[expr, 4,  VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Below], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]