# Constructing symbol definitions for With

Tags: function-construction, syntax

I would like to be able to define two arrays, one containing symbol names and one containing the values of those symbols, for use in constructs such as `With`.  For example:

```
params = {a,b,c,d};
vals = {1,2,3,4};
With[{a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4},Print["Do something fancy"]]
```

I would like to construct the local variable assignment array {a=1, b=2, ....} automatically.  The wishful-thinking solution of `With[params = values, ...]` doesn't work and I've tried a random selection of Mapping, Threading and Holding, all to no avail.  It looks like a similar [question has been answered before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280/reassign-values-to-symbols), however, the function proposed by [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) doesn't work in the `With` block.  I suspect my issue focuses on an attempt to manipulate Symbols in a non-trivial manner (and by non-trivial, I simply mean anything beyond a = 1).

Comment: did you try rule assignments, instead of an assign operator?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is my version using [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937):

```
ClearAll[myWith];
SetAttributes[myWith,HoldAll];
myWith[pars_=vals_,body_]:=
    Apply[Set,Hold[Evaluate[Transpose[{pars,vals}]]],{2}]/. 
        Hold[vars_]:>With[vars,body]
```

This code assumes that `pars` evaluate to a list of symbols. For example,

```
myWith[params=vals,a+b+c+d]

(* 10 *)
```

Comment: I'm always confused by the `Hold`, `Evaluate` and `:>` etc in your answer. A neat method anyway, learn a lot from this :)

Answer (score 9):

Borrowing from [Mr. Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121) [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/how-to-set-block-local-variables-by-code/19761#19761) to a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/how-to-set-block-local-variables-by-code), I came up with the following.

```
ClearAll[myWith];

SetAttributes[myWith, HoldAll];
myWith[vars_ = init_, expr_] := 
 Function[Null, With[{##}, expr], HoldAll] @@
  (Thread[Hold[Set][Hold[vars], Hold[init]] /. {x__} :> x, Hold] /. Hold[Set] -> Set)
```

Examples

```
Clear[a, b, c, d];
a = 10;
myWith[{a, b, c, d} = {1, 3, 5, 7}, Range[4].{a, b, c, d}]
(* 50 *)

myWith[{a, b, c, d} = {10, 3, 5, 7}, Range[4].{a, b, c, d}]
(* 59 *)
```

It works with only one assignment (`Set`) in the first argument, as in the example in OP.  One might wish to extend it to arbitrarily many (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: This works well, and I'm not the least bit surprised I couldn't come up with the answer on my own.

Answer (score 7):

As has been stated in other answers the two basic methods of insertion are described in:
[How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19758/how-to-set-block-local-variables-by-code)

I'll pick the "injector pattern" as did Leonid, but with apologies to him that code seems much too complicated for such a simple operation.  I would use this:

```
SetAttributes[listWith, HoldAll];

listWith[(set : Set | SetDelayed)[L_, R_], body_] :=
  Inner[set, L, R, Hold] /. _[x__] :> With[{x}, body]
```

Additionally this code has been designed to support the (undocumented) `SetDelayed` form of `With` and works with held Symbols and values.

---

*Edit:*
Sadly not as clean but more robust, handling e.g. held variables and non-held values or vice versa:

```
SetAttributes[listWith, HoldAll];

listWith[(set : Set | SetDelayed)[L_, R_], body_] :=
  set @@@ Thread[Hold @@@ {L, R}, Hold] /. _[x__] :> With[{x}, body]
```

---

Basic example:

```
params = {a, b, c, d};
vals   = {1, 2, 3, 4};

listWith[params = vals, a + b + c + d]

params
```

> ```
> 10
>
> {a, b, c, d}
> ```

Advanced example:

```
{a, b, c, d} = {0, 0, 0, 0};                       (* other existing assignments *)
params = Hold[a, b, c, d];                         (* held Symbols *)
vals   = Hold[2 + 2, 8/4, Sin[Pi], 1/0];           (* held values *)

listWith[params := vals, HoldForm[a + b + c + d]]  (* note := *)

{a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> (2+2) + 8/4 + Sin[π] + 1/0
>
> {0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Definitely one of the things I like most about M.SE is the wealth of knowledge users are willing to contribute; having a software package that can do so many things in so many ways helps as well.

Comment: @bobthechemist It's nice, isn't it?  And to think some people believe an acceptable SE question should have [only one answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193432/are-there-any-legitimate-reasons-for-adding-more-than-one-answer-to-a-question/193433#comment605913_193433). :^)

Comment: @bobthechemist I was hoping that you might Accept this answer.  The presently selected answer fails if any of the symbols you use (`a,b,c,d`) have global values for example.  This also allow you to conveniently use the `:=` method in `With`.  Are these not valuable to you?

Comment: I will take this under consideration.  This project took a back burner role now that school is starting so I haven't had a chance to play around with your answer.

Comment: @bobthechemist Thanks, that's all I could ask.

Comment: @bobthechemist Say, did you ever get back to play around with this?  I still think I have the best code on the page. :^)

Comment: Sadly no; too many projects going on and I haven't gotten back to the project that required this functionality, so at the moment I can't fairly evaluate how your solution compares to the accepted one for my application.

Comment: @bobthechemist No problem, but you should expect that I'll rib you about it at least once a year. :o)

Comment: Squeaky wheel gets the rep. (or something like that)

Answer (score 5):

If we say that `=` is the same as a `->`, we can do the following:

```
With[{list={#1->#2}&@@@Thread[{params,vals}]//Flatten},
    (* fancy operation*)
    {a,b,c,d}/.list
]

==> {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Maybe a bit cumbersome, but it does the job. (Please have a look down to @TomD's comment which makes this specific approach even much cleaner and simpler)

You could do this as well:

```
With[{tmp$=Quiet@Set[#1,#2]&@@@Thread[{params,vals}]},
    (* fancy operation *)
    Range[4] . {a,b,c,d}
]

==> 30
```

Since we're using `With` we've to assign to something. That's why there is `tmp$`. We don't need to use replacement with this anymore.

This seems a little hacky and Mathematica complains (sometimes) about assigning to raw objects etc. That's why there is a `Quiet`...

With this approach you can go up with arbitrary arguments. Like so:

```
params = ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"];
vals = Range[26];

With[{tmp$ = Quiet@Set[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread[params -> vals]},
    #*2 & /@ ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"]] // Total

==> 702
```

Having showed that, I don't think that there isn't any need for a *macro* or overloading of standard built-in functionality.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to write a "macro" that expand  at the first element of `With`. It's rather hard for me .

Comment: Nice workaround; I will have to see if this works for my project.

Comment: You second method doesn't work in my version 9. The output is `a + 2 b + 3 c + 4 d`.

Comment: @mm.Jang ups...i need to check that...

Comment: @mm.Jang checked it and it works with 9...

Comment: @Stefan I don't really know what happened, can't reproduce this anymore. I believe I copied the code in a right way.

Comment: @mm.Jang i know exactly what you mean...fiddling around with replacements it is sometimes best to start with a fresh kernel...or do the replacements inside a `With`.

Comment: Or, perhaps a bit simpler, `With[{list = Thread[params -> vals]},(*fancy operation*){a, b, c, 
   d} /. list]`

Comment: @TomD...uff...yes you're right. that's much simpler and clean...thank you. didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly interpreted the question, you want to define a list of variables and related values externally to a With construct, and then inside the With you want to automatically assign those values to variables, but without to influence the values of such variables outside the With itself. In other words, exactly what With does, but using parallel assignments in automatic. 
Because parallel assignment is not allowed inside scoping constructs like With (and Module for instance) the effort is to find a way to overcome such limit.
Some solutions offered in previous answers are not fully working, despite the apparent correct behavior. See for instance the following

```
Clear[a,b,c,d];

params = {a, b, c, d};
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4};
With[{list = {#1 -> #2} & @@@ Thread[{params, vals}] // 
    Flatten},(*fancy operation*){a, b, c, d} /. list]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

it seems it works, but looking at other operations

```
params = {a, b, c, d};
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4};
With[{list = {#1 -> #2} & @@@ Thread[{params, vals}] // Flatten},
 (*fancy operation*)
 e = a + b + c + d;
 Print[{a, b, c, d} /. list];
 Print[e]]
```

> {1,2,3,4}
>
> a+b+c+d

event the other solution seems to have a side effect that at the end vanishes the use of With.

```
Clear[a,b,c,d];

params = ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"];
vals = Range[26];
With[{tmp$ = Quiet@Set[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread[params -> vals]}, #*2 & /@ 
   ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"]] // Total
```

> 702

the result is correct but the variables inside params are now defined outside the With statement, and this makes unuseless the With itself

```
params
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}

```
vals
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}

so starting from the solution proposed by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), then I found an easier solution.

```
Clear[a,b,c,d];

myWith[vars_List, values_List, expr_] := Module[vars, MapThread[Set, {vars, values}]; expr]

myWith[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, Range[4].{a, b, c, d}]
(* 50 *)
myWith[{a, b, c, d}, {10, 3, 5, 7}, Range[4].{a, b, c, d}]
(* 59 *)

{a, b, c, d}
```

> {a, b, c, d}

```
myWith[ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"], 
  Range[26], #*2 & /@ ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"]] // Total
```

> 702

and still the variables are not defined outside the With

```
ToExpression@CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z}

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
myWith[vars_ = init_, expr_] := 
              Function[Null, With[{##}, expr], HoldAll]@@(Thread[Hold[Set][Hold[vars],
              Hold[init]]/.{x__} :>x, Hold] /. Hold[Set] -> Set)
```

seems to have problems with

```
myWith[a = {1, 2}, a - b]
```

It is only when the variables are a list that the `{x___}->x` is appropriate.

Perhaps it is more transparent to use a `Replace` rather than `Function` as per below:

```
ClearAll[myWith];
SetAttributes[myWith, HoldAll];
myWith[{vars__} = {inits__}, expr_] := 
     Replace[(Thread[Hold[Set][Hold[vars], Hold[inits]], Hold] /. 
     Hold[Set] -> Set),
     Hold[assignments___] :> With[{assignments}, expr]];
myWith[var_ = init_, expr_] := With @@ Hold[{var = init}, expr];
```