# Assign variables from list inside With or Module

Tags: evaluation, syntax, scoping

I have found that it is possible to assign variables from lists, as follows.

```
r = {1, 2, 3};
{a, b, c} = r;
b
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

However, if I try to do this within a `With` or `Module` statement, it does not evaluate:

```
With[{{x, y, z} = r}, x]
Module[{{x, y, z} = r}, x]
```

> ```
> With[{{x, y, z} = r}, x]
> Module[{{x, y, z} = r}, x]
> ```

whereas I expected it to work as:

```
With[{x = r[[1]], y = r[[2]], z = r[[3]]}, y]
Module[{x = r[[1]], y = r[[2]], z = r[[3]]}, y]
```

> ```
> 2
> 2
> ```

or even:

```
Module[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = r; y]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Why is this? Is there an accepted way to do this?

Comment: [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/5478)

Comment: Exactly this question [was asked on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373526/error-generating-localized-variables-as-constants/) some time ago.

Comment: Leonid's linked question is exactly what I was asking, with excellent responses. I've tried to flag this as a duplicate, but as it's not a Mathematica SE page I'm unable to.

Comment: @Gyppo This is not really a dupe here, since SO is a separate site. This leaves some room for further answers, possibly better than those in that SO question, unless that question gets migrated from SO. I would personally add / change some things in my answer there, but no time for that right now.