# How to speed up calculations with large number of replacement rules?

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement

In my program I have an expression which looks like:

```
AnalyticalExpression = 2^(-1-n-np)R^(-2+n+np)(8np1f[-2+n+np,-1+p1+p1p,1+p2+p2p,1+q1+q1p,3+q2+q2p]-8np1f[-2+n+np,-1+p1+p1p,3+p2p2p,1+q1+q1p,1+q2+q2p]-4np1f[-2+n+np,p1+p1p,p2+p2p,q1+q1p,4+q2+q2p]+...)
```

I gave here a short example; full expression is few pages long.
From my point of view, this expression serves as a function of the integer variables n,np,p1,p1p,q1,q1p,... and two real variables R,x. My program evaluates the above expression by using a replacement rule, for instance:

```
tmp = AnalyticalExpression /. {n->2,np->3,p1->0,p2->4,...}
```

The problem is that the program has to evaluate this expression hundreds of thousands times with different values of these integer variables. This makes the whole program painfully slow. Is there a tricky way to perform this substitution efficiently? Tabulation of AnalyticalExpression for every combination of the integer variables seems quite weird to me...

Thanks in advance for the answers and suggestions.

Michal

Comment: It is still not exactly clear what you do and whether the slow down comes from the large expression or the substitution. Are you changing the values in the list of replacement rules? Have you seen the function [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html)?

Comment: Why don't you make it a function with named arguments?

Comment: I can. Would it change the cost of the evaluation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As halirutan comments [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) will speed the application of long lists of rules:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

n = 1500;
big = Sum[Expand[(RandomInteger[99] + a[i])^RandomInteger[9]], {i, n}];

vals = RandomInteger[9999, n];
rules = Thread[Array[a, n] -> vals];

big /. rules           // timeAvg
big /. Dispatch[rules] // timeAvg
```

> 0.936
>
> 0.008608

Somewhat faster, you could convert your entire expression into an anonymous [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) *one time*, and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) it to your list of values:

```
big2 = Function @@ {big} /. Dispatch@Thread[Array[a, n] -> Array[Slot, n]];

big2 @@ vals // timeAvg
```

> 0.004496

For variety, if all of the expressions to replace are Symbols you could use a variation of `listWith` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30646/121).  It is between the two others in speed in this test.

```
syms = Table[Symbol["a" <> ToString@i], {i, n}];

big3 = big /. Dispatch@Thread[Array[a, n] -> syms];

SetAttributes[listBlock, HoldAll];
listBlock[(set : Set | SetDelayed)[L_, R_], body_] := 
  Inner[set, L, R, Hold] /. _[x__] :> Block[{x}, body]

listBlock[syms = vals, big3] // timeAvg
```

> 0.005368

This has the advantage of keeping your expression in the normal form rather than turning it into a `Function`.

---

### Optimizing the expression

In light of the nature of the [actual expression](http://pastebin.com/ugwCA0Dw) which contains a number of repeated sub-expressions we can improve the performance a bit by exploiting this commonality.  An internal function exists that attempts this automatically: `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression ``.  You can search the site for "OptimizeExpression" for more details and other examples of use.

With your full expression assigned to `fullAE`:

```
vars = Variables@Level[fullAE, {-1}];
rules = MapIndexed[Function[{a, b}, a -> Slot[b[[1]]]], vars];

func = Function @@ {fullAE} /. rules;

optimized = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[fullAE];
funcOptimized = Function @@ optimized /. rules;

values = RandomInteger[99, 12];
```

Timings for the incrementally faster methods:

```
fullAE /. Thread[vars -> values]          // timeAvg
fullAE /. Dispatch@Thread[vars -> values] // timeAvg
func @@ values                            // timeAvg
funcOptimized @@ values                   // timeAvg
```

> 0.00324
>
> 0.0022208
>
> 0.001048
>
> 0.0006752

Comment: Thank you for your answers, halirutan and Mr. Wizard. Unfortunately, Dispatch[] does not improve the timings significantly because I change the integer values in the replacement rule at every evaluation. At the very beginning of the evaluation the replacement rule looks like {n->0,np->0,p1->0,p2->0,...} and the last may be {n->10,np->10,p1->10,p2->10,...}. Therefore, I have to generate a dispatch table as many times as the replacement rule is applied. This is clearly not the same situation as in the halirutan's example.

Comment: @michal Actually, I specifically included the creation of the `Dispatch` table within the timing loop to address that situation.  (Of course I may have made a mistake).  How long are your replacement rule lists?  I chose 1500; if yours are short `Dispatch` may not help much.  What is the `LeafCount` of your expression?

Comment: My replacement rule is about 20 entries long. Now I realised that yours is 1500 entries long. LeafCount[] of my expression is 11562.

Comment: @michal Could you put the entire expression on http://pastebin.com/ ? If it can't be compiled there may not be a lot more than can be done beyond the options I have given.

Comment: Do you mean to paste the exact (explicit) form of AnalyticalExpression (as abbreviated in the body of the question)?

Comment: @michal Yes.  The specific expression may allow or rule out certain methods, such as using `Compile`.  It would also help to know the approximate range of values for your substitutions.

Comment: There you go, http://pastebin.com/ugwCA0Dw. However, this expression contains other symbolic quantities which are replaced in the next step...

Comment: @michal Well, that rules out compilation, but I'll still try to find some way to optimize this.

Comment: I've already tried to manipulate this mess in a way but I'm afraid it's beyond me... I'll be indebted if you take a look.

Comment: @michal I only find 12 symbols that appear to be variables rather than functions: `{a, n, np, p1, p1p, p2, p2p, q1, q1p, q2, q2p, R}` -- are these the only ones you will be substituting (in this step)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Other 8 symbols were dummy and I forgot to delete them (an artifact from the previous version of the code). Nonetheless, removing them improves timings by 1-2% only so the problem is still alive. {a, n, np, p1, p1p, p2, p2p, q1, q1p, q2, q2p, R} are variables; a,R are real, the others are integers.

Comment: @michal I updated my answer with an automatic method.  There *may* be further optimizations to be had, but I need to move on to other things.  I'll try to return to this problem but I'll admit up front I have a poor record when it comes to returning to problems.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Wizard. The speed up you have presented is already significant since calculations will surely take weeks anyway (due to its nature).