# is there a way to speed up rule replace?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am currently doing calculation with 7 parameters, each parameter set corresponding to a value. And I store the data in the format as a list of rule, like following

```
{{100, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1/5, 0} -> 0.00720852, {100, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1/5, 0} ->
   0.00456272, {100, 7, 1, 3, 1, 1/5, 0} -> 0.00363628, {100, 7, 1, 4, 1, 1/5, 0} -> 
  0.0034754, {100, 7, 1, 5, 1, 1/5, 0} ->0.00343746, {100, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1/5, 0} -> 
  0.00342957, {100, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1/5, 0} -> 0.0034},........}
```

I put all my calculated data into a single rule list, I name it `generaldata`

when I want to extract data from the `generaldata` used for plotting, I would write the following code for example

```
extractdata = Table[Table[{100, 7, line, distance, 1, 1/5, delta}, {line, 1, long + 1}, {distance, 1, 12}], {delta, 0, 1, 1/50}] /. generaldata
```

currently, my `generaldata`'s length is 88000, and it took me 40 seconds to accomplish the rule replacement. It is quite slow. I also tried Parallel it

```
data = ParallelMap[Replace[#, generaldata] &, 
    Table[Table[{100, 7, line, distance, 1, 1/5, delta}, {line, 1, long + 1}, {distance, 1, 12}], {delta, 0, 1, 1/50}], {3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

and this took even longer about 200 seconds on an 8 core machine.

What's more, I only calculated a small part of the data I wanted. So I can foresee, if I don't improve the method, the time cost will be much more.

So I am asking here for a better quicker method.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is this parallel evaluation with Dispatch\[\] so slow?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25263) In short, this is a bug in the parallel functions... using `Rule` in any parallel function makes it exceptionally slow.

Comment: @rm-rf What?! why this is a duplicate????! My main question is not why parallel is slow. My question is to get a quicker method to extract the data I wanted.

Comment: @rm-rf maybe this is a duplicate.http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31613/how-to-speed-up-calculations-with-large-number-of-replacement-rules?rq=1 . I am reading now

Comment: @rm-rf OK, I understand. `Dispatch` speed up rule replacement significantly. I never knew `Dispatch` before. `Dispatch`'s awesome efficiency impressed me.