# Evaluate the NDSolveValue at the condition point with replacement

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, warning-messages

I try to Evaluate something with replacement

```
Block[{{t1, t2} = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == 1., x'[0.] == 0., 
 WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {"StopIntegration"}]}, {Indexed[
  x["Domain"], {1, -1}], x[Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}]]}, {t, 
 0., 100.}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]}, t1 + t2]
```

But it gets an `Block::lvset` error, but if I compute

```
{t1, t2} = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == 1., x'[0.] == 0., WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {"StopIntegration"}]}, {Indexed[
x["Domain"], {1, -1}], x[Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}]]}, {t, 0., 100.}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]
t1 + t2
```

is ok. So how can I compute it in one expression?

Comment: `Block` doesn't support the syntax `Block[{{t1,t2}=…}`, please check the document carefully. Simplest fix is probably `Block[{t1, t2}, {t1, t2} = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0., x[0.] == 1., x'[0.] == 0., 
 WhenEvent[x'[t] > 0., {"StopIntegration"}]}, {Indexed[
  x["Domain"], {1, -1}], x[Indexed[x["Domain"], {1, -1}]]}, {t, 
 0., 100.}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001]; t1 + t2]`. If you want to create a `Block` that supports this syntax, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/1871

Comment: @xzczd, thank you so much!