# Function of arguments given in non-fixed order

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments, argument-patterns

normally we define functions as

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] := ArcSin[x^2*y/z]
```

however when one has many arguments (as I do) I find difficult to remember what is the meaning of the argument "number 2", that is y in the above example. Of course a `?f` would do the job of refreshing  my memory ... but I want to find another solution, possibly more direct.

I would like to achieve the definition of a function that evaluates independently of the order in which I give the arguments, still keeping their meaning. For this I thought to exploit the nice feature of Options patters that are non-positional.

```
  Options[disorderedf] = {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}
  disorderedf[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    ArcSin[OptionValue[x]^2*OptionValue[y]/OptionValue[z]]
```

which beautifully evaluates the same independent of the order I give the values of the three coordinates

```
disorderedf[x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> Pi]
```

> ```
> ArcSin[3/π]
> ```

```
disorderedf[y -> 3, z -> Pi, x -> 1]
```

> ```
> ArcSin[3/π]
> ```

First of all I would like to ask if this is reinventing the wheel because *Mathematica* has already some type of functionality to support this way of giving arguments.

Secondly I wanted to ask if there are suggestions to speed up or simplify this or get the same behavior with simpler and more easily extendable code. I am imagining that I might in the future add more arguments and the way I did it might not be the most economical one.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think what you show is a perfectly reasonable way to obtain the desired behavior.

Comment: I believe this question can be considered a duplicate of [(55833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55833/121).  Your method is the same as the one I proposed there, so clearly I agree with Daniel that it is a reasonable way to go.  I do show some variations that I think may interest you so please take a look at my answer.  Then let me know if you feel that this question should *not* be closed.

Comment: Hi Mr.Wizard, yes I think both our solutions and our questions are very similar. Thanks for pointing out your post. I am still looking into it to figure out the details and see how I can improve my current function.