# Defining functions when there are a lot of parameters

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Suppose I have two lists of parameters: $\delta=\{\delta1, \delta2, …\}$ and $\gamma = \{\gamma1, \gamma2, …\}$.

**The question is:** how can one use $\delta$ and $\gamma$ (the parameter vectors) within a function definition to avoid typing out all of the parameters one-by-one? That is, how can I write $F[\delta \_,\gamma\_] :=...$ instead of having to type out all the individual parameters as in: $F[\delta1\_,\delta2\_,..., \gamma1\_,\gamma2\_,...] :=...$?

NOTE: Below is some code that generates the parameter vectors that I would like to use within the function definition:

```
Nobs = 5; 
\[delta] = 
  Symbol[#] & /@ Table[l[i] = “\[delta]" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Nobs}];
\[gamma] = 
  Symbol[#] & /@ 
   Table[l[i] = “\[gamma]" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Nobs}];
```

PS: sorry this is somewhat of an odd question... But my problem has a lot of parameters, and this is a possible fix.

Comment: while one can do what you describe I hardly can believe it really is what you want. Doesn't Davids answer do exactly what you want? You probably should describe more clearly what your ultimate goal is...

Comment: If delta and gamma  are treated each as one unit in g then you simply use f[x_, y_] := g[Sequence @@ x, Sequence @@ y]

Comment: This question is confusing.  I agree with Albert that it is unlikely that you actually want to do what (he interprets that) you write.  Some questions that may be related to your goal:  [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121),
[(15749)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121),
[(26686)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121),
[(52057)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52057/121),
[(55833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55833/121)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and sorry for the confusion. I will try to edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I would not recommend to do what follows except for certain special cases and I'm almost sure that there is a better solution for your actual problem than this. Nevertheless, what you ask for can be done like this:

```
Nobs = 10;
d = Symbol[#] & /@ Table["d" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Nobs}];
g = Symbol[#] & /@ Table[ "g" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, Nobs}];

With[{
    dargs = Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ d),
    gargs = Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ g)
  },
  f[dargs, gargs] := Evaluate[h[d, g]]
];
```

by checking downvalues you can verify that it did what you want:

```
DownValues[f]
```

The trick here is as usual to look at the `FullForm` of the pattern you want to generate:

```
FullForm[x_]
```

this, plus applying `Sequence` to the list of patterns are the two building blocks which make the above code do what it does...

Answer (score 2):

Define your function with list variables and be sure that your function definition on the right-hand side applies to lists (as in this case of `Total`).

```
f[x_List, y_List] := Total[x] Total[y];

f[{3}, {4}]
```

(* 12 *)

```
f[{3, 6}, {4}]
```

(* 36 *)

```
f[{3, 6}, {4, 2, 1}]
```

(* 63 *)

Answer (score 2):

If you have need of individually addressing the parameters by name you could use:

```
δ = {δ1, δ2, δ3, δ4, δ5};
γ = {γ1, γ2, γ3, γ4, γ5};

Quiet[toPattern[s_Symbol] := s_]

foo[toPattern /@ δ, toPattern /@ γ] := {δ3/γ1, δ4/γ3, δ5/γ5}
```

Check:

```
?foo
```

> ```
> Global`foo
>
> foo[{δ1_,δ2_,δ3_,δ4_,δ5_},{γ1_,γ2_,γ3_,γ4_,γ5_}] := {δ3/γ1, δ4/γ3, δ5/γ5}
> ```

```
foo[{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}]
```

> ```
> {5/2, 7/6, 9/10}
> ```

In most cases such things are not necessary.  If you give a broader context for your question a different method may be recommended.