# Using Block with a list of variables

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment

I have a list of variables

```
var={v1,v2};
```

which I want to protect/localize during a particular operation. I have decided that I want to use `Block` and if I write

```
Block[{v1,v2},Print[4]]
```

everything is fine but what I really need is to somehow implement the functionality:

```
Block[vars,Print[4]]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121), [(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121), [(19758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121),
[(28610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/121),
[(31708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121),
[(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)

Answer (score 8):

Storing `v1` and `v2` in a variable makes it more complicated. It is better to construct custom dynamic environments based on `Block`, which would be closures, closed over symbolic variables you want.

Here is a generator for such environments:

```
withBlockedVars = Function[vars, Function[code, Block[vars, code], HoldAll], HoldAll];
```

Here is how you generate a particular one you need (`v1` and `v2` here may have global values, this doesn't matter):

```
myBlock = withBlockedVars[{v1, v2}]

(* Function[code$, Block[{v1, v2}, code$], HoldAll] *)
```

What you get is a closure, with your specific variables embedded into it. Here is how you can use it:

```
{v1, v2} = {1, 2};
myBlock[Print[{v1, v2}]]

(* {v1,v2} *)
```

If you insist on using `var`, you can do it like so:

```
myBlock = Hold[var] /. OwnValues[var] /. Hold[val_]:> withBlockedVars[val],
```

and then continue in the same way as above.

Answer (score 6):

Using my `bump` function (horrible name, sorry) from [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/elegant-manipulation-of-the-variables-list/17553#17553):

```
func_[bump[lst_, idx___], arg___] ^:= 
  func[#, arg] & @ Part[List @@@ Unevaluated @@ {lst}, {1}, idx]

{v1, v2} = {7, 9}; (* existing values *)

vars = Hold[v1, v2];

Block[bump[vars], Print[v1, ", ", v2]]
```

> ```
> v1, v2
> ```

See the linked question for many other uses of this flexible function.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it turns out that what I was looking for was a simple use of `Evaluate`, *i.e.* the following code:

```
var={v1,v2};
Block[Evaluate[var],Print[4]]
```

does the trick, provided there are no values assigned to v1 and v2. If that is an important consideration, the more complicated code from the other answers can be used, but for me the above simple solution proved sufficient.

As Mr.Wizard pointed out in the comments the above code allows for assignments to the variables that are only local. For example the code

```
var={v1,v2};
Block[Evaluate[var],v1=1;v2=2;{v1,v2}]
```

returns

```
{1,2}
```

whereas

```
var={v1,v2};
Block[Evaluate[var],v1=1;v2=2;{v1,v2}];
{v1,v2}
```

returns

```
{v1,v2}
```

demonstrating that the local assignments do not affect the global variables.

Once more, as Leonid points out, if there are assignments made to the variables initially, the code fails and more elaborate solutions are needed.

Comment: This is not as simple as that. There are reasons that the other answers are more complex. If your variables `v1` and `v2` have global values, then your code would fail, while the other answers would not.

Comment: I guess you are trying to protect a global symbol from lasting modification.  This does work, but `Sequence` appears superfluous; you could instead write: `Block[Evaluate[var], v1 = "local";]` and observe that the global value of `v1` is not changed.  Also you have `vars` where I you meant `var` within `Block`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : Thanks for the corrections. I will edit to incorporate them. Nevertheless Leonid's point remains valid: We are free to do local assignements to `v1` and `v2` within the `Block`, but if we give some global values to them before the above code, it doesn't work. For me personally, that is not a problem as all the variables are undefined.