# How to transfer the list of parameters values into With

Tags: programming

In the following case:

```
With[{x=1,y=2},Print[x+y]]
```

the values of `x` and `y` are declared in the list of local variables. How to transfer the values of x and y into With[] from an external list, like:

```
abc:={x=1,y=2}; With[abc,Print[x+y]]
```

This list of values must be understood in my case as true only when it is applied (locally true).

Comment: e.g. `Unevaluated[With[abc, Hold[x + y]]] /. OwnValues[abc]` there should be a nice duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @Kuba - it's kind of hard to search for posts **about** `With`

Comment: May I suggest *not* to do this, because expressions like `{x=1}` evaluate naturally and their evaluation has significant consequences (setting `x`).   They can be kept unevaluated, but it's difficult and error-prone to do so. Instead store the parameter values in a list of rules (or association) and use something like the `withRules` function I describe [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/993/12).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121),
[(10322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121),
[(19758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121),
[(28610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/121),
[(31708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121),
[(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121),
[(75417)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75417/121)