# Set does not work

Tags: evaluation, core-language, variable-definitions

I tried following code, but it does not work as expected:

```
Do[Set[a[[1]],a[[2]]],{a,{x->2,y->5,z->x+y}}]
```

> ```
> {x,y,z}
> ```

I want the result to be `{2,5,7}`, but it becomes just `{x,y,z}`.
I tried `a[[1]]=a[[2]]` instead of `Set[a[[1]],a[[2]]]`, but it does not work too.

I tried the following code, and it works well:

```
hoge[x_, y_] := x = y
Do[hoge[a[[1]],a[[2]]],{a,{x->2,y->5,z->x+y}}]
{x,y,z}
```

But this needs extra function and is not so smart. Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Quick fix: `Do[Set @@ a, {a, {x -> 2, y -> 5, z -> x + y}}]` but it will fail anyway, as soon as `x/y/z` have values. related: [28610](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/5478), also see links in [103628](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103628/how-to-transfer-the-list-of-parameters-values-into-with?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kuba. It worked. And I found that in the first code I set the first element of list `a` with `a[[2]]`, and it is the failure.

Comment: Related, and recommended reading: [(280)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121), [(6511)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121), [(6669)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121), [(10322)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Set` is specially [overloaded](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55503/280) for `Part` in order to allow in-place modification of the expressions:

```
a = x -> 2;
a[[1]] = 1; a
```

> ```
> 1 -> 2
> ```

It is documented on the Documentation page for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (the first point under "Details" section):

> You can make an assignment like `t[[spec]]=value` to modify any part or sequence of parts in an expression. »

Your function `hoge` doesn't `Hold` its arguments and hence passes to `Set` the extracted *variable* (a `Symbol`) instead of the `Part` expression what explains why it "works" for you:

```
hoge[x_, y_] := Hold[x = y]
a = x -> 2;
hoge[a[[1]], a[[2]]]
```

> ```
> Hold[x = 2]
> ```

---

For your particular purpose the simplest approach is to replace `Rule` by `Set`:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
{x -> 2, y -> 5, z -> x + y} /. Rule -> Set
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 7}
> ```

Another method is to `Apply` `Set` effectively replacing the head `Rule` by `Set`:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
Set @@@ {x -> 2, y -> 5, z -> x + y}
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 7}
> ```

Inside of `Do`:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
Do[Set @@ a, {a, {x -> 2, y -> 5, z -> x + y}}];
{x, y, z}
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 7}
> ```