# Defining local variables in a dynamic way in Module

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, scoping

I have a function whose variable are specified by a input parameters of function:

```
ParametersList1 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
ParametersList2 = {{"a", 3}, {"b", 4}}

TestFunction[ParametersList_] := Module[{},
Table[ToExpression[ParametersList[[n]][[1]] <> "=" <> ToString[ParametersList[[n]][[2]]]], 
{n, 1, Length[ParametersList]}];
Return[a + b]
]

TestFunction[ParametersList1]
3

TestFunction[ParametersList2]
6
```

The function works as expected, however, the parameter a and b should not be global. The number of parameters given by ParametersList is not known and I cannot explicitly describe it as Module[{a,b},...]. Is there anyway to define local variables in a dynamic way, for example, something like following?

```
Module[ToExpression[ParametersList[[All, 1]]],...]
```

Comment: You could go with something like [**783**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478) but if you are using `a` or `b` explicitly too, you may end up with contex issues for more complicated cases. There are ways to deal with this too but if you are on v10+ then maybe  `vars = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>; vars["a"] + vars["b"]` instead of `ParametersList1/2`?

Comment: a+b is rather complicated equation with many parameters and I would like to avoid adding vars[" "] for all of them.

Comment: It seems from your code that you not only don't know the number of parameters but also not their names. So what use is it to assign values to some parameters of unknown names? You wouldn't be able to do `a+b` because you don't know that they are called `a` and `b`. Why then not just working with the list as it is? `Return[Total[ParametersList[[All,2]]]]`

Comment: Btw, how do you get `6` for `TestFunction[ParametersList2]`?

Comment: Could you provide a context, is this a tool for you to be used in a notebook or do you want to create a package for others, etc?

Comment: Related:  [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121), [(28610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/121), [(31708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121), [(75417)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75417/121), [(134381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134381/121#136543)

Comment: @Felix, I I like to make a tool for scientific calculations and "a+b" is a formula that appears in physics. For example, I like to make a library to calculate AreaOfCircle=radius * radius * Pi, which takes the "radius" from Parameterslist={"radius",1}. Since the number of parameters are huge, I like to avoid giving explicit parameters like. TestFunction[a_,b_,c_,...].

Comment: @Kuba and to make the code more easily readable, I like to avoid hiding the name of parameters either (like following). TestFunction[Parameterlist],  Return[ Parameterlist[1]^2*Pi ]. I like to explicitly show the equation in the definition of function as "AreaOfCircle=radius * radius * Pi."

Comment: @arb would that be convenient? `param1 = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>;
param2 = <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>;

TestFunction[params_] := 
 Function[{a, b}, a + b] @@ params[[{"a", "b"}]]; TestFunction[param1]`

Comment: @Kuba, this looks also useful, but I cannot test it with my version of mathematica. Would be nice if explicit specification of {a,b} can be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of [How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121) or at least very similar.

```
Attributes[stringModule] = HoldRest;

stringModule[par : {{_String, _} ..}, body_] := 
  Join @@ Cases[
     MapAt[MakeExpression, par, {All, 1}],
     {_[s_Symbol], v_} :> Hold[s = v]
  ] /. _[sets__] :> Module[{sets}, body]
```

Test:

```
a = b = "Failed!";

ParametersList1 = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}};
ParametersList2 = {{"a", 3}, {"b", 4}};

stringModule[ParametersList1, a + b]
stringModule[ParametersList2, a + b]
```

> ```
> 3
>
> 7
> ```

I use `Cases` and the pattern `{_[s_Symbol], v_} :> Hold[s = v]` to make sure that assignments are possible, so that malformed input is skipped, e.g.:

```
stringModule[{{"a", 3}, {"b", 4}, {"2c", 1}}, a + b + 2c]
```

> ```
> 7 + 2 c
> ```

`2c` is not a Symbol and therefore cannot be assigned so it is ignored.

Related:

- [Functions with changeable global variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134381/121)

Comment: +1 though OP wanted to have `a+b` hardcoded, which is a bad idea and at the and we would end up with this solution anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.

Comment: @arb great, but it isn't what you asked for, your formulas are hardcoded inside your `TestFunction` and you only provide parameters. Please consider updating the question if that was not the main point.

Comment: @Kuba I prefer hardcoded formula, but I am not sure if I insist on it, if it cannot be easily done. Is there any restriction on what formulas I could use in the parameter of stringModule[] function, compared with hardcoding it? I plan to use Mr.Wizard's suggestion as 
TestFunction[ParametersList_] := Module[{temp},
temp=stringModule[ParametersList1, a + b];
Return[temp]
] This seems to satisfy my needs.

Comment: @arb I am glad I could help. If you find this answer fully satisfactory please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nice ! +1