# Why am I not getting a numeric response?

Tags: programming

### Code

```
In[830]:= curvature[x_, y_, z_, t_] :=
 With[{s = {x, y, z}},
  With[{v = D[s, t]},
   With[{ fT = v / Norm[v]},
    With[{fK = D[fT, t] / Norm[v]},
     Norm[fK]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
curvature[ Cos[t], Sin[t], t, t] /. t -> 1 // N

Out[831]= \[Sqrt](0.5 Abs[-0.59501 - 
      0.0955129 (-0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.540302] + 
         0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.841471])]^2 + 
   0.5 Abs[-0.382051 + 
      0.148752 (-0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.540302] + 
         0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.841471])]^2 + 
   0.015625 Abs[-0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.540302] + 
      0.909297 Derivative[1][Abs][0.841471]]^2)
```

### Question

I have a // N there.

Why do I not get a numerical answer. Instead, why do I have Derivative[1][Abs] all over the place?

Thanks!

### EDIT

The following "fixes" the code. Why?

```
myNorm[lst_] := Sqrt[lst . lst]
curvature[x_, y_, z_, t_] :=
 With[{s = {x, y, z}},
  With[{v = D[s, t]},
   With[{ fT = v / myNorm[v]},
    With[{fK = D[fT, t] / myNorm[v]},
     myNorm[fK]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
curvature[ Cos[t], Sin[t], t, t] /. t -> 1 // N
```

This returns 0.5

Comment: I like your tendency to make code immutable (nested `With`). You should really try my [`LetL` macro](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/metaprogramming-in-mathematica) (section "Examples of new scoping constructs / environments"), to reduce the boilerplate. With it, your code becomes `curvature[x_, y_, z_, t_] :=
 LetL[{s = {x, y, z}, v = D[s, t], fT = v/myNorm[v], 
   fK = D[fT, t]/myNorm[v]}, myNorm[fK]]`. For definitions made with `SetDelayed`, it expands at definition - time, so you do get a nested `With` in your function's definition.

Comment: @Leonid: Your mathematica.stackexchange.com answers read like chapters in a book. :-)

Comment: Thanks :) They are in a sense, a future book which I hope to finish one day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the chain rule of differentiation, $(f\circ g)'(t)=f'(g(t))g'(t)$. Look at:

```
D[Abs[Sin[t]], t]
(* Cos[t] Derivative[1][Abs][Sin[t]] *)
```

You have several `Abs[Sin[t]]` cropping up everywhere due to `Norm[v]` in your code.

---

I would suggest re-writing the function as:

```
Clear[curvature2]
curvature2[vec : {x_, y_, z_}, t_] := 
    With[{norm = Simplify[Norm@#, t ∈ Reals] &},norm[D[#/norm@#, t]/norm@#] &@D[vec, t]]

curvature2[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t}, t]
(* 1/2 *)
```

Comment: Why are those not evaluated when I have already assigned t -> 1 ?

Comment: `Abs[Sin[x]]` is not differentiable everywhere. So if you just give it a general form, it will happily differentiate `Abs`

Comment: @RM: Interesting, so defining myNorm with sqrt fixes this. So basically, the core of the problem is that Mathematica's Norm uses abs?

Comment: @term-rewritica What norm _doesn't_ use `Abs` or some equivalent notion of _length_?

Comment: @RM: why did square root of dot product "work" then?

Comment: because there is no `Abs`... you're simply taking the derivative of $\sin^2(x)$, etc., not $|\sin(x)|^2$. You got lucky because this is the 2-norm. What if you needed the 3-norm? $\sqrt[3]{t^3 + \cos^3(t) + \sin^3(t)}$ is not a norm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4079/discussion-between-term-rewritica-and-r-m)