# Derivative of the Absolute Value Function in Mathematica looks very different from the actual answer

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

Derivative of the `Abs` Function in *Mathematica* looks very different than the actual answer. Why? How to correct this?

For example I entered `D[Abs[x - 1], x]` and got the output  `Abs'[-1 + x]`. I was hoping to get the output in this form: `(x−1)/|x−1|`.

Is there a syntax error in my input?

Comment: `FullSimplify[D[Abs[x - 1], x], x \[Element] Reals && x != 0]`

`Resolve[ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals && x != 0, 
  Sign[-1 + x] == 
   Piecewise[{{1, x - 1 > 0}, {-1, x - 1 < 0}}]], Reals]`

Comment: How do I get the output in this form: (x−1)/|x−1| ?

Comment: Throw a rule and traditionalform onto end of simplify, `/. Sign[z_ - 1] :> (z - 1)/Abs[z - 1] // TraditionalForm` or investigate `ComplexityFunction` and `TransformationFunctions` for simplify. Bottom line, the form presented is what *Mathematica* deems the "simplest". If you need/want to transform it, you need to tell it so.

Comment: Thanks!  ComplexExpand followed by Simplify helped.

Comment: You need ComplexExpand probably because you can't take the derivative of Abs in the complexes

Comment: `D[Abs[x - 1], x] // ComplexExpand // Simplify` gives only `(-1 + x)/Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]`.

Comment: That's the closest I could get to the form: (x−1)/|x−1|

Comment: What about the forms given by `D[Abs[x - 1], x]~FullSimplify~(x \[Element] Reals)`

Comment: Well, `Abs[x-1]` is in fact not differentiable in the classical sense at `x=1`. So `x-1/|x-1|` would only be the right answer for `x != 1`.

Answer (score 16):

In version 11.1 the function `RealAbs` was introduced that give your desired result

```
D[RealAbs[x - 1], x]
RealAbs'[x - 1]

(*(-1 + x)/RealAbs[-1 + x]*)
(*(-1 + x)/RealAbs[-1 + x]*)
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @murray, you can use `ComplexExpand`

```
D[Abs[x - 1], x] // ComplexExpand // Together
(*(-1 + x)/Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]*)
```

Or explicitly state that $x$ is real, as @Rojo said

```
D[Abs[x - 1], x] // FullSimplify[#, x \[Element] Reals] &

(*Sign[-1 + x]*)
```

However, `FullSimplify` changes the domain slightly because `Sign[-1 + x]` is defined at $x=1$

```
Sign[x - 1] /. x -> 1
(*0*)

RealAbs'[x - 1] /. x -> 1
(*Indeterminate*)
```

Comment: `RealAbs'[x - 1]==Sign[x - 1]` are equal.Check: `Limit[{RealAbs'[x - 1], Sign[x - 1]}, x -> 1, 
   Direction -> #] & /@ {-1, 1}`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk their limits are equal at x=1, but try this `{FunctionDomain[RealAbs'[x - 1], x], FunctionDomain[Sign[x - 1], x]}`

Comment: `{FunctionDomain[
  Simplify[RealAbs'[x - 1], Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals}], x], 
 FunctionDomain[Sign[x - 1], x]}`  ?

Comment: @user45937  Hi. `D[Abs[x - 1], x] // ComplexExpand // Together` failed in v13.

Comment: @lotus2019 in v13.2.1 it returns `(-1 + x)/Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]`

Comment: @user45937 OK, thank you. It seems that I need to upgrade the version.

Answer (score 8):

It has been mentioned before (for example, see this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8189/45431)) that [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs) in Mathematica is defined for complex numbers. Since [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs) is not holomorphic over the complex numbers, its derivative is not well-defined. One way to see this is:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[z] == Sqrt[z Conjugate[z]]]
```

> True

Here are a couple more ways to achieve what you want (besides those mentioned by @roman).

1. Use `Sqrt[z^2]` instead of `Abs[z]`:

`D[Sqrt[z^2], z]`

> z/Sqrt[z^2]

2. Use complex [(Wirtinger)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) derivatives. Summarizing:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right), \quad\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$$

This means that the "real" derivative, i.e., the derivative with respect to $x$ only, is given by:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$$

Hence the "real" derivative of `Abs[z]` is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left| z \right| = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{z \bar{z}} = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2 \left| z \right|} = \frac{\Re{z}}{\left| z \right|}$$

which agrees with the previous answer when $z$ is real.

However, this exposition is not useful without an actual implementation of Wirtinger derivatives! On the other hand, in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143739/45431) I give such an implementation, and the function is called `ComplexD` (I provide its definition at the end of this answer). So:

```
ComplexD[Abs[z], z] + ComplexD[Abs[z], Conjugate[z]]
% //FullSimplify
```

> z/(2 Abs[z]) + Conjugate[z]/(2 Abs[z])
>
> Re[z]/Abs[z]

in agreement with the above results. It would be possible to define a `RealD` function:

```
RealD[expr_, z_] := ComplexD[expr, z] + ComplexD[expr, Conjugate[z]]
```

if one were so inclined. Here is the definition of `ComplexD` (slightly edited from the original):

```
ComplexD[expr_, z__] := With[
    {
    nc = NonConstants -> Union @ Cases[{z},
        s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol] | {s_Symbol | Conjugate[s_Symbol], _} :> s
    ],
    old = OptionValue[
        SystemOptions[],
        "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions"]
    },

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        With[{new = Join[old, {Abs, Conjugate}]},
            SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions" -> new]
        ];
        Unprotect[Conjugate, Abs];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] := 0;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] := Conjugate[D[f, Conjugate[w], nc]];
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] := D[Conjugate[f]f, w, nc]/(2 Abs[f]),

        D[expr, z, nc],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> old];
        Conjugate /: D[w_, Conjugate[w_], nc] =.;
        Conjugate /: D[Conjugate[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Abs /: D[Abs[f_], w_, nc] =.;
        Protect[Conjugate, Abs];
    ]
]
```