# Free Convective Heat Transfer of Non-Newtonian Power Law Fluids from a Vertical Plate

Tags: differential-equations, physics, finite-difference-method, discontinuity, heat-equation

I am trying to solve a set of PDEs mentioned in [this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c0pdsp9y3c994d/Finite%20Difference%20Solution%20of%20Free%20Convective%20Heat.pdf?dl=0) with `NDSolve` but facing quite a few issues.

The PDE system is:

```
pde1 = D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y] == 0;
pde2 = D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + 
   v[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
  D[Abs[D[u[t, x, y], y]]^(n - 1)*D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + 
   a*T[t, x, y] - b*u[t, x, y];
pde3 = D[T[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[T[t, x, y], x] + 
   v[t, x, y]*D[T[t, x, y], y] == 1/c*1/d*D[T[t, x, y], y, y];
```

with initial and boundary conditions:

```
ics = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, T[0, x, y] == 0};
bcs = {u[t, 0, y] == 0, v[t, 0, y] == 0, T[t, 0, y] == 0, 
   u[t, x, 0] == 0, v[t, x, 0] == 0, T[t, x, 0] == 1, 
   u[t, x, 10] == 0, T[t, x, 10] == 0};
```

The parameters in the system are:

```
a = 5; b = 4; n = 2; c = 3; d = 10;
```

Now when I try to solve it numerically by

```
sol = NDSolve[
  Join[{pde1, pde2, pde3}, bcs, ics], {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y], 
   T[t, x, y]}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

Among numerous warnings, I get this one first

> Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations
>   will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations.

The notebook version of my trial can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnf92fu2778q5p8/pdesol.nb?dl=0).

Am I asking too much from `NDSolve` or there is mistake I am making?

The paper linked above has solved the PDE system with finite difference method (FDM), is it possible to implement it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: `T[0,0,0]` is both `0` and `1`

Comment: @Feyre You are right! But the error still persists.

Comment: It should be: `pde2 = D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x] + 
   v[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
  D[Abs[D[u[t, x, y], y]]^(n - 1)*D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + 
   a*T[t, x, y] - b*u[t, x, y]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You are absolutely right! Thanks. But I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I was just doing that. Thanks dear.

Comment: @MMM  The derivative of the absolute value of a function is not well defined and will cause problems.  See, for instance the question and comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47100/1063).  I suggest you find some other way to express this quantity, the details depending on the underlying problem you are trying to address.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I never thought about this. So to make things simple, the removed the `Abs` as test case but still no promising results.

Comment: @MMM  The first message states that `pde1` contains no time derivative, which is not a problem.  The second message states that `T[t, x, 0] == 1` is inconsistent with `T[0, x, y] == 0` on the edge `{0, x, 0}`, which could be a problem.  The third message states that another boundary condition in `y` is needed, which may not be true.  I recommend that you address the second message, which may cause the third message to go away too.  It is too soon to worry about the fourth message.  I also recommend that you think about whether `u` and `v` can be represented as the divergence of a scalar.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for your constant interest in the question. In the manuscript, the authors have solved the system with FDM. Is it possible to do FDM in `Mathematica`? To be honest, I am not sure what to do, just wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `NDSolve`-based solution

To solve the equation set with `NDSolve`, we need to resolve several issues:

1. As mentioned by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) in the comment above, `Abs` can't be differentiated properly in *Mathematica*. (This design is reasonable: do remember argument of `Abs` can be a complex number! ) This can be circumvented by rewriting `Abs` with `Sqrt[(*……*)^2]` i.e. modifying `pde2` to

   ```
   pde2[a_, b_, n_: 2] = 
    D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] (D[u[t, x, y], x]) + v[t, x, y] D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
     D[Sqrt[D[u[t, x, y], y]^2]^(n-1) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + a T[t, x, y] - b u[t, x, y]
   ```
2. The i.c.s and b.c.s are inconsistent, in this case it isn't a big deal actually, anyway, we can minimize its influence by setting a large `"ScaleFactor"` inside `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"`, or modifying the 6th b.c. to `T[t, x, 0] == 1 - E^(-1000 t)` if you want to avoid the warning.
3. The equation set doesn't involve `t` derivative of `v`. This is the most troublesome part for solving the problem. Though `NDSolve` claims that "the  equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations"  in the `pdord` warning, it seems that the DAE solver of `NDSolve` is still not strong enough. I circumvent the issue by modifying `pde1` to:

   ```
   With[{eps= 10^-0}, pde1 = D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y] == D[v[t, x, y], t] eps]
   ```

   i.e. by adding a `D[v[t, x, y], t]` term to the right hand side of `pde1`. You may feel it ridiculous. "Come on! At least use a smaller `eps`!" Nevertheless, this approximation turns out to be good enough. Let's discuss it later.

The following is the complete code:

```
Clear[a, b, c, n, d, pde2, pde3]
With[{eps = 10^-0}, pde1 = D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y] == D[v[t, x, y], t] eps];
pde2[a_, b_, n_: 2] = 
 D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] (D[u[t, x, y], x]) + v[t, x, y] D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
  D[Sqrt[D[u[t, x, y], y]^2]^(n-1) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + a T[t, x, y] - b u[t, x, y];
pde3[c_, d_: 10] = 
  D[T[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] D[T[t, x, y], x] + v[t, x, y] D[T[t, x, y], y] == 
   1/c 1/d D[T[t, x, y], y, y];
ics = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[0, x, y] == 0, T[0, x, y] == 0};
With[{lb = 10}, bcs = {{u[t, 0, y] == 0, v[t, 0, y] == 0, T[t, 0, y] == 0},
    {u[t, x, 0] == 0, v[t, x, 0] == 0, T[t, x, 0] == 1},
    {u[t, x, lb] == 0, T[t, x, lb] == 0}}];

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
        "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines",
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {tf, "ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

Clear@solfunc
With[{pts = 70, lb = 10}, 
 solfunc[a_, b_, c_, tend_: 1, n_: 2, d_: 10] := 
  NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2[a, b, n], pde3[c, d], bcs, ics}, {u, v, T}, {t, 0, 
    tend}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, lb}, Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]]]

(sollst[#] = solfunc[5, 4, #]) & /@ {1, 2, 4}; // Quiet

Plot[sollst[#][[1]][1, 1, y] & /@ {1, 2, 4} // Evaluate, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[sollst[#][[3]][1, 1, y] & /@ {1, 2, 4} // Evaluate, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's not clear to me that the *Figure-1* in the paper is sliced at which time, but the following seems to give the same result as *Figure-1(a)*:

```
(sollst[#, 1] = solfunc[5, 4, #, 1, 1]) & /@ {1, 2, 4};

Plot[sollst[#, 1][[1]][1, 1, y] & /@ {1, 2, 4} // Evaluate, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally let's check the influence of the `D[v[t, x, y], t]` term:

```
ListPointPlot3D[sollst[1][[2]]["ValuesOnGrid"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPointPlot3D@sollst[1][[2]]["ValuesOnGrid"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As one can see, the value of `D[v[t, x, y], t]` is negligible in most part of the  domain.

**Remark**

1. If you take the `// Quiet` away, you'll see `NDSolve` spit out `Power::infy` and `Infinity::indet` warning, further check shows these warnings come out in the pre-process stage i.e. from `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``. This may be considered as a bug, but anyway `NDSolve` still manage to solve the equation set.
2. In principle we should obtain a not-too-bad result even if we don't explicitly set `Method` inside `NDSolve`, but actually without the `Method` option `NDSolve` will spit out `ndnum` and fails. Further check reveals that, this warning also comes out in the pre-process stage i.e. from `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations ``. I think it's a bug.
3. The `Abs` issue can also be circumvented by rewriting `Abs` with `Piecewise` or `Unitstep`, with the help of `PiecewiseExpand` and the undocumented function `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``:

   ```
   pde2[a_, b_, n_: 2] = 
    D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] (D[u[t, x, y], x]) + v[t, x, y] D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
      D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[D[u[t, x, y], y]], Reals]^(n - 1) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + 
       a T[t, x, y] - b u[t, x, y] // Simplify`PWToUnitStep

   With[{pts = 70, lb = 10}, 
    solfunc[a_, b_, c_, tend_: 1, n_: 2, d_: 10] := 
     NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2[a, b, n], pde3[c, d], bcs, ics} /. 
       nu_ de_^index_ :> Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Simplify[nu de^index], {u, v, T}, {t, 0, 
       tend}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, lb}, Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]]]
   ```

   In this case `` /. nu_ de_^index_ :> Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Simplify[nu de^index] `` is added inside `NDSolve`, or `pde2` will evaluate to an equation involving fraction when `n` isn't an `Integer`, which makes `NDSolve` spit out `ndnum` and fails. (I believe it's the same bug as mentioned in 2nd remark. ) A trivial advantage of this circumvention is, it never triggers the `Infinity::indet` warning, and doesn't trigger the `Power::infy` warning when `n` is an `Integer`.
4. If you decide to circumvent the `Abs` issue via the solution in 3rd remark, then I'd like to tell you that `` // Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` in the definition of `pde2` isn't necessary i.e. rewriting `pde2` with `Piecewise` is enough to circumvent the `Abs` issue, but this makes `NDSolve` spit out the `eerr` warning and be about 10 times slower. The only benefit seems to be, when `n` is an `Integer`, the possible bug mentioned in the 2nd remark is not triggered i.e. we can get a slightly distorted result without explicitly setting `Method` in `NDSolve`:

   ```
   pde2[a_, b_, n_: 2] = 
     D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] (D[u[t, x, y], x]) + v[t, x, y] D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
      D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[D[u[t, x, y], y]], Reals]^(n - 1) D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + 
       a T[t, x, y] - b u[t, x, y];
   With[{lb = 10}, 
    solfunc[a_, b_, c_, tend_: 1, n_: 2, d_: 10] := 
     NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2[a, b, n], pde3[c, d], bcs, ics}, {u, v, T}, {t, 0, tend},
       {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, lb}]]
   (sollst[#] = solfunc[5, 4, #]) & /@ {1, 2, 4}; // AbsoluteTiming
   Plot[sollst[#][[1]][1, 1, y] & /@ {1, 2, 4} // Evaluate, {y, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
5. The main reason for choosing `1` as the value of `eps` is, if `eps` is smaller, `NDSolve` is likely to spit out `ndsz` warning and fails.
6. When $n<1$, `pde2` is singular at $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. I failed to find a way to remove the singularity. (I doubt if it's removable. Can this be the nature of the model?) Anyway, a possible work-around is to use a slightly different i.c.:

   ```
   ics = With[{icv = 10^-6 y}, {u[0, x, y] == icv, v[0, x, y] == icv, T[0, x, y] == icv}]
   (* pts = 30 *)
   (sollst[#] = solfunc[5, 4, #, 1, 1/2]) & /@ {1, 2, 4}; // AbsoluteTiming
   (* Takes about 200 seconds *)
   ```

## FDM-based solution

Here's an implementation for the finite difference scheme in the paper, which is much faster than the `NDSolve`-based one:

```
ClearAll[fw, bw]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw};
fw@D[expr_, x_] := Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + delta@x}, {x -> x}})/
 delta@x
bw@D[expr_, x_] := Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> x - delta@x}})/
 delta@x

Clear[delta]
delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0

Clear[a, b, c, n, d, formula]
formula@1 = bw@D[u[t, x, y], x] + bw@D[v[t, x, y], y] == 0;
formula@2 = fw@D[u[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] bw@D[u[t, x, y], x] + 
    v[t, x, y] fw@D[u[t, x, y], y] == 
   bw@D[Abs@fw@D[u[t, x, y], y]^(n - 1) fw@D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + gr T[t, x, y] - 
    m u[t, x, y];
formula@3 = fw@D[T[t, x, y], t] + u[t, x, y] bw@D[T[t, x, y], x] + 
    v[t, x, y] fw@D[T[t, x, y], y] == 1/pr 1/re bw@D[fw@D[T[t, x, y], y], y];

step@2 = Solve[formula@2, u[t + delta[t], x, y]][[1, 1, -1]];
step@3 = Solve[formula@1, v[t, x, y]][[1, 1, -1]];
step@4 = Solve[formula@3, T[t + delta@t, x, y]][[1, 1, -1]];

var = Alternatives @@ {u, v, T};
trans[y_ + k_. delta@y_] := y + k
trans[y_] := y
(*symb[delta]=Δ;symb@index=i;symb@end=end;*)
getstepsize[x_] := (delta@x = end@x/(index@x - 1))
getindex[x_] := ( index@x = end@x/delta@x + 1)
table := Table[0., {index@x}, {index@y}]


solver = ReleaseHold@With[{g = Compile`GetElement, rc = RuleCondition},
    Hold@Compile[{end@t, delta@t, n, pr}, 
           With[{m = 4, gr = 5, re = 10}, 
            With[{index@x = 50, index@y = 50, end@x = 1, end@y = 10}, 
             With[{getstepsize@x, getstepsize@y, getindex@t},
              Module[{u = table, v = table, T = table},
               T[[All, 1]] = Table[1., {index@x}];
               Do[u[t, x, y] = step@2;
                v[t, x, y] = step@3;

                T[t, x, y] = step@4, {t, index@t}, {x, 2, index@x}, {y, 2, 
                 index@y - 1}]; {u, v, T}]]]], CompilationTarget -> C, 
           RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. OwnValues@table /. 
        Flatten[DownValues /@ {step, getstepsize, getindex}] /. (l : var)[x__] :> 
        rc@g[l, Sequence @@ trans /@ Rest@{x}] /. 
      HoldPattern@(h : Set | AddTo)[g@a__, b_] :> 
       h[Part@a, b] /. (head : end | delta | index)@x_ :> 
      rc@Symbol[ToString@(*symb@*)head <> ToString@x]];

sollst = solver[5, 1/150, 2, #] & /@ {1, 2, 4}; // AbsoluteTiming
solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}] & /@ # & /@ sollst;
(* {0.479751, Null} *)
```

The output of `solver` is the value of `u`, `v`, `T` at the end time. I don't restore previous data because <strike>the implementation will become more troublesome then</strike> I think you're only interested in steady state.

Well, I admit some advanced techniques are used in this code piece, for the purpose of making implementation of FDM less tedious. To understand it, you may want to read the following posts:

[When should I, and when should I not, set the HoldAll attribute on a function I define?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4126/1871)

[Is there a way to simplify this replacement rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33056/1871)

[How to make the code inside Compile conciser without hurting performance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47485/1871)

[Why is CompilationTarget -> C slower than directly writing with C?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132130/1871)

[Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/1871)

Finally an illustration for the result:

```
Plot[solfunclst[[All, 1]][1, y] // Through // Evaluate, {y, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ContourPlot[solfunclst[[1, 1]][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually, why not replace `Abs[f]` with `Sqrt[f^2]` and sidestep the piecewise conversion altogether?

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate your efforts. I have couple questions. 1) When I try some other values of `n=0.5, 1.5, 3` I am getting an error.  2) How to plot `(Abs[D[u[1, 1, y],y]])^(n) at y=0 vs n`? 3) How to plot contours of `u[t,x,y]' for various values of n?

Comment: @mmm 1) Check my edit. 2) Notice the output of `solfunc` is a list of solution, the 1st one is the solution for `u`, the 2nd one for `v`, the 3rd one for `T`, so e.g. `solfunc[5, 4, 1, 1, n][[1]]` is a solution for `u`. To obtain a list of `(Abs[D[u[1, 1, y],y]])^(n)` at `y=0` vs `n`, you can e.g.: `Table[Abs@D[solfunc[5, 4, 1, 1, n][[1]][1, 1, y], y]^n /. y -> 0, {n, 1, 2}]`, then you can use `ListLinePlot` to get the picture. 3) Contour of which variable?

Comment: @J.M. You're right, though this circumvention triggers some warning, it's feasible. Check my edit for more details.

Comment: Contour of `u[5,x,y] vs (x,y)` for different values of `n`.

Comment: @mmm Try a larger `eps` e.g. `eps =10^2`

Comment: I still didn't get the contour plot. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mmm Well, I think it's quite straightforward. What have you tried?

Comment: I am using this `ContourPlot[
 sollst[#][[1]][1, x, y] & /@ {1, 2, 4} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 
  0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 180, Frame -> True` but the contours does not make any sense.

Comment: I was looking for some sort of smooth curve but with this `ListLinePlot[
 Table[Abs@D[solfunc[5, 4, 1, 1, n][[1]][1, 1, y], y]^n /. y -> 0, {n,
    1, 5, 1}]]` I am not getting it.

Comment: @mmm Of course, because `ContourPlot` doesn't accept this syntax. Just compare the result of `ContourPlot[Cos[x] Cos[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` and `ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` and `ContourPlot[{Sin[x] Sin[y], Cos[x] Cos[y]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`. For more details, check the document of `ContourPlot` carefully. As to the `ListLinePlot` issue, the step size is too large, try something like `{n, 1, 5, 1/5}`, you may also need to adjust the `InterpolationOrder` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50512/discussion-between-mmm-and-xzczd).

Comment: @xzczd How to change the boundary conditions? From `u=T=0` at `y=0` to  `u=T=1` at `y=0` and `v=0` remain the same.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal Just modify `{u = table, v = table, T = table}` to `{u = Table[1., {index@x}, {index@y}], v = Table[0., {index@x}, {index@y}], 
 T = Table[1., {index@x}, {index@y}]}`. (The code can be modified in a conciser way, but I think this modification is easier to understand. )

Comment: @xzczd Please have a look, I don't know where I am making a mistake. https://www.dropbox.com/s/otzgxjczzl6untx/FDM.nb?dl=0

Comment: @maple If `K0` is another independent variable, add it to the first argument of `Compile`; `c` isn't initialized, it need to be first defined in the same way as `u`, `v`, `T`, etc.; your PC doesn't have a C compiler installed, or your C compiler isn't successfully configured, if speed isn't that important, simply take away the `CompilationTarget` option, or search in this site to find the proper way to configure a C compiler.

Comment: @xzczd `K0` is a parameter, I kept it zero, `{gm = 2, N1 = 3, S1 = 0, Sc = 6, K0 = 0}` the new dependent variable is `c[t,x,y]`. With the conditions of the old problem it is working but if i change it then its not working.

Comment: @Maple `solver[5, 1/150, #, 6] & /@ {2, 4, 6}` triggers `CompiledFunction::cfne` but `solver[5, 1/150, 1, 6]` works well, so this isn't a coding issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55950/discussion-between-maple-se-area-51-proposal-and-xzczd).

Comment: It is possible to vary time as we are varying x and y in the FDM-based solution?

Comment: @zhk What do you mean by "vary time"?

Comment: I meant to say that if the end time is 5 then I’m unable to see what happened at t=0.5. What I’m looking for is to see variations in the dependent variables wrt t, x, y. Let say, I want to visualise u vs t, x , y using parametricplot3d.

Comment: @zhk It's possible to modify the program of course, but given the current version is already fast, I suggest you to simply modify the end time and use the obtained data to build a new `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: Sir when is i run the FDM-based solution it gives the error (CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::nocomp: A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers. >>
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>)

Comment: @HabibUllah As indicated by the warning, your PC doesn't have a C compiler installed or the C compiler isn't properly configured. You can simply remove the `CompilationTarget -> C` option, but I do recommend you to install a C compiler (or configure it properly, if you've already installed one), that'll make the code faster.