# Solve nonlinear coupled PDE with x,y and t dependent

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am trying solve the following two coupled PDE equations.

∂f/∂t=(∂^2 f)/(∂x^2 )+(∂^2 f)/(∂y^2 )-1/f^3  [(∂B/∂x)^2+(∂B/∂y)^2 ]-f+f^3

(∂^2 B)/(∂x^2 )+(∂^2 B)/(∂y^2 )-B*f^2+2/f [(∂B/∂x)(∂f/∂x)-(∂B/∂y)(∂f/∂y)]=0

The boundary conditions are

B(t,0,y)=const*t,B(t,x,0)=B(t,x,10),B(t,10,y)=0,

f(t,10,y)=1,f(t,x,0)=f(t,x,10),

Initial condition

f(0,x,y)=1 and B(0,x,y)=0

In order to solve I set up a square region {x=0,10 and y=0,10}.Left wall we don't know how f behaves.When time ramp up applied B increases so I need to know how B and f changes with time inside the box.

When I try to solve I get following errors:

1.NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations.

2.NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.

**I have following questions:**

**1.Is it possible to solve this type of coupled pde using ndsolve?**

**2.Is there any method I can use to over come this error?**
Please help..I am new to Mathematica..
Code is as follows.here u==f and v==B**

```
 h = 0; inf = 10; k = 3;
pde = {D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
    D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + 
     D[u[t, x, y], {y, 
       2}] - (k^4/u[t, x, y])^3*(D[v[t, x, y], y]^2 + 
        D[v[t, x, y], x]^2) - u[t, x, y] + u[t, x, y]^3, 
       D[v[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + 
     D[v[t, x, y], {y, 2}] - (v[t, x, y]*u[t, x, y]^2)/k^2 + 
           (2/u[t, x, y])*(D[u[t, x, y], x]*D[v[t, x, y], x] - 
        D[u[t, x, y], y]*D[v[t, x, y], y]) == 0}; 
ic = {u[0, x, y] == 1, v[0, x, y] == 0};
bc = { u[t, inf, y] == 1, v[t, 0, y] == h + 0.1*t, 
   v[t, x, 0] == v[t, x, inf], u[t, x, 0] == u[t, x, inf], 
   v[t, inf, y] == 0}; 
NDSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, {u, v}, {x, 0, inf}, {y, 0, inf}, {t, 0, 15}];
Table[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[u[t, x, y] /. First[%]], {x, 0, inf}, {y, 0, inf}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10, Mesh -> False], {t, 14, 15}]
```

Comment: 1. The equation in the code is slightly different from the one at beginning, for example the `+f-f^3` part. BTW it's bad idea to name variables differently in code and text, this makes error checking painful. 2. Boundary at `u[t, 0, y]` is missing, this is a more serious problem, because we don't know what b.c. is added, for more information, check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871 3. The equation causing `pdord` warning is indeed troublesome, you can refer to this post as an example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133731/1871

Comment: Thank you for the comment.Yes I made a mistake with equation. I adjusted it.For the error pdord can be removed if I add  D[v[t, x, y], t]  to second equation.Then I get error for the  insufficient boundary condition and error with NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.02421591489423537`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected..The problem can solve in Matlab but it long process because we need to adjust the equation according to specified model in matlab.That is why I want to try out in Mathematica see that I can solve it with very few lines.

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, b.c. for `u[t, 0, y]` is necessary, or a hidden b.c. will be added (which we don't know what it represents at least for now. You may also want to read [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28033/5331)). Also, notice the warning `ndsz` is easy to explain. If you check the solution of `u` at `0.0242`, you'll see it hits `0`, which isn't allowed by the equation.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.I will read it.