# Error in the solution of PDE with NDsolve and method of lines

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity, boundary-conditions, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve a system of the partial differential equation with the help of NDSolve and method of lines.

Mathematica code for the above-described problem is

```
Clear[B, lm, Pr, pde1, pde2, pde3]
pde1 = D[u[t, x, r], x]+ D[v[t, x, r], r] + v[t, x, r]/r == 0;
pde2 = D[u[t, x, r], t]+u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x]+v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r]==T[t, x, r]+(1/(1+lm))*(D[u[t, x, r], r,r]+(1/r)*D[u[t, x, r], r]+B*(D[u[t, x, r], r,r,t]+D[v[t, x, r], r]*D[u[t, x, r], r,r]+v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r,r,r]+D[u[t, x, r], r]*D[u[t, x, r], x,r]+u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x,r,r]+(1/r)*D[u[t, x, r], r,t]+v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r,r]/r+u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x,r]/r));
pde3 = D[T[t, x, r], t]+u[t, x, r]*D[T[t, x, r], x]+v[t, x, r]*D[T[t, x, r], r]==(1/Pr)*(D[T[t, x, r], r,r]+D[T[t, x, r], r]/r);

(*with initial and boundary conditions:*)

ics = {u[0, x, r] == 0, v[0, x, r] == 0, T[0, x, r] == 0};
With[{lb=10}, bcs = {{u[t, 0, r] == 0, v[t, 0, r] == 0, T[t, 0, r] == 0}, {u[t, x, 1] == 0, v[t, x, 1] == 0, T[t, x, 1] == 1}, {u[t, x, lb] == 0, (D[u[t,x,r], r] /. r -> lb) == 0,T[t, x, lb] == 0}}];

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n,"MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}} mol[tf : False | True, sf_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines","Differentiate\[Beta]oundaryConditions" -> {tf,"ScaleFactor" -> sf}}

Clear@solfunc With[{pts = 20, lb = 20}, solfunc[B_, Pr_,lm_, tend_] := NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2[B,lm], pde3[Pr], bcs,ics}, {u, v, T}, {t, 0, tend}, {x, 0, 1}, {r, 0, lb}, Method -> Union[mol[pts, 4], mol[True, 100]]]] (sollst[#] = solfunc[#, 0.7, 0.5, 10]) & /@ {0.1, 0.2}; // Quiet

Plot[{sollst[#][[1]][1, 1, r] & /@ {0.1} // Evaluate, sollst[#][[1]][1, 1, r] & /@ {0.2} // Evaluate}, {r, 0, 10},  PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True]
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: "But it doesn't work..." is really a lazy and useless problem description. This fits really well to the usage of `Quiet`. Please, start to _read_ error messages. That will help you to figure what went wrong. Also sprinkle a couple of semicoli, in particular in the line starting with `Clear`.

Comment: You seem to use `pde2` and `pde2` as functions, but they are not defined as such. Something that you could have inferred from reading the error messages...

Comment: Side note: OP is refering to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133731/1871).

Comment: Sir when I change domain tp [0,1] in this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133731/free-convective-heat-transfer-of-non-newtonian-power-law-fluids-from-a-vertical) problem its also not working... `u[t, x, 1] == 0, v[t, x, 1] == 0, T[t, x, 1] == 1`

Comment: and sir when I run this code its doesn't show me an error. So, please help me how can I get an error box.

Comment: Just remove `Quiet`. It's only purpose is to suppress error and warning messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 12, the solution method (DAE) is automatically selected

```
pde1 = D[u[t, x, r], x] + D[v[t, x, r], r] + v[t, x, r]/r == 0;
pde2 = (D[u[t, x, r], t] + u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x] + 
     v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r] == 
    T[t, x, r] + (1/(1 + lm))*(D[u[t, x, r], r, r] + (1/r)*
         D[u[t, x, r], r] + 
        B*(D[u[t, x, r], r, r, t] + 
           D[v[t, x, r], r]*D[u[t, x, r], r, r] + 
           v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r, r, r] + 
           D[u[t, x, r], r]*D[u[t, x, r], x, r] + 
           u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x, r, r] + (1/r)*
            D[u[t, x, r], r, t] + v[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], r, r]/r + 
           u[t, x, r]*D[u[t, x, r], x, r]/r)));
pde3 = (D[T[t, x, r], t] + u[t, x, r]*D[T[t, x, r], x] + 
     v[t, x, r]*
      D[T[t, x, r], r] == (1/Pr)*(D[T[t, x, r], r, r] + 
       D[T[t, x, r], r]/r));

(*with initial and boundary conditions:*)
lb = 10; B = .5; Pr = .7; lm = .1;
ics = {u[0, x, r] == 0, v[0, x, r] == 0, T[0, x, r] == 0};
bcs = {u[t, 0, r] == 0, v[t, 0, r] == 0, T[t, 0, r] == 0, 
   u[t, x, 1] == 0, v[t, x, 1] == 0, T[t, x, 1] == 1 - Exp[-5 t], 
   u[t, x, lb] == 0, (D[u[t, x, r], r] /. r -> lb) == 0, 
   v[t, x, lb] == 0, T[t, x, lb] == 0};


{U, V, Ts} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2, pde3, bcs, ics}, {u, v, T}, {t, 0, 
     10}, {x, 0, 1}, {r, 1, lb}] // Quiet;
```

Visualisation

```
With[{t = 10}, {DensityPlot[U[t, x, r], {x, 0, 1}, {r, 1, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "u"], 
  DensityPlot[Ts[t, x, r], {x, 0, 1}, {r, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> "T"]}]

{Plot[U[t, 1, 1.19], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> u], 
 Plot[U[10, 1, r], {r, 1, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> u], 
 Plot[Ts[t, 1, 1.19], {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> T], 
 Plot[Ts[10, 1, r], {r, 1, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> T]}
```

[image: Fig 1]

Comment: thank you so much, dear **Alex Trounev** for your helpful comment.

Comment: Sir Why we take boundary condition `T[t, x, 1] == 1 - Exp[-5 t]`insted of `T[t, x, 1] == 1`

Comment: @Mathematicain This is a damping factor for matching initial and boundary conditions. This is similar to parameter "ScaleFactor"  in the"MethodOfLines".

Comment: Dear **Alex Trounev**, thank you so much.