# How do I plot the derivative of a function with absolute values?

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[D[Abs[x], x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

gives out several lines of error messages and an empty plot.

```
Plot[Derivative[1][Abs[#1] & ][x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

just gives out an empty plot.

How do I plot $\left(\left|x\right|\right)^\prime$?

Comment: derivative of |x| is  x/|x|, so you can use that. `Plot[x/Abs[x], {x, -10, 10}]`

Comment: Also related: [8188](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/simplifying-the-derivative-of-x)

Answer (score 9):

Using `PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], x \[Element] Reals]` instead of `Abs[x]`:

```
Plot[Evaluate@ D[PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], x \[Element] Reals], x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

You can convert `Abs` to `Piecewise` for real arguments using `PiecewiseExpand`:

```
absToPW[x_] := PiecewiseExpand[Abs[x], x \[Element] Reals]
absToPW[z]
```

[image]

which you can differentiate

```
D[absToPW[z], z]
```

[image]

and plot

```
Plot[Evaluate@{absToPW[x], D[absToPW[x], x]}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: In that case, I'm curious why won't this: `Plot[D[Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}, Indeterminate], x], {x, -10, 10}]` work? Especially since `D[Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}], x]` gives out `Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {1, x > 0}}, Indeterminate]`, and `Plot[Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {1, x > 0}}, Indeterminate], {x, -10, 10}]` works nicely?

Comment: Ah, right. Having seen the other answer I now know that I should've typed `Plot[Evaluate[D[Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}, Indeterminate], x]], {x, -10,10}]` instead, which works neatly. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Is there still a reason to define `absToPW` as you do here instead of using the command RealAbs (recently introduced)? If not, then perhaps it is worth updating this answer to mention that one can just use `RealAbs`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the simplest way is just define the absolute value function yourself, e.g.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {-x, x < 0}}]
Plot[Evaluate[D[f[x], x]], {x, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

Comment: +1 the problem is that mathematica doesn't knows how to differentiate `Abs`

Answer (score 3):

To extend the other answers, if you're going to be using the derivative of `Abs` often in your computations and do not need the complex absolute value, then you can define the [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html) of `Abs` once and for all, using whichever formula for the derivative of `Abs` you find convenient.

```
Derivative[1][Abs][x_] = Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {-1, x < 0}}, Indeterminate];
Plot[Evaluate@D[Abs[x], x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that one must use `Evaluate` on the derivative. (see, for instance, [General::ivar is not a valid variable when plotting - what actually causes this and how to avoid it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/generalivar-is-not-a-valid-variable-when-plotting-what-actually-causes-this)).

To [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) the definition, do the following:

```
Derivative[1][Abs][x_] =.
```

You can also localize the definition of the derivative to a block of code as follows:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Derivative},
 Derivative[1][Abs][x_] = Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {-1, x < 0}}, Indeterminate];
 ...
 <code>
 ...
 ]
```

The definition of `Derivative` is automatically reset in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite it as

```
Plot[Evaluate @ ComplexExpand @ D[Abs[x], x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

But I would rewrite it as

```
dAbs[x_] = ComplexExpand @ D[Abs[x], x];
Plot[dAbs[x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}]
```

Both produce

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `UnitStep`:

```
f[a_] := (x - a) (UnitStep[x - a] - UnitStep[-(x - a)])
Plot[Evaluate@D[f[5], x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> 0]
```

[image]