# Mathematica tries to differentiate Abs[x] and this causes a problem?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I am trying to run the following code:

```
f[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], Cos[t]}
s = 0.1;
s1 = 2;

t[u_] := Normalize[f'[u]]
n[u_] := Normalize[t'[u]]
b[u_] := t[u]\[Cross]n[u]

Graphics3D[
 {
  BSplineCurve[Table[f[u], {u, 0, 2 Pi, s}]],
  Arrow[Table[{f[u], t[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, s1}]],
  Arrow[Table[{f[u], n[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, s1}]]
  }
 ]
```

It works fine until I ask it to compute `Arrow[Table[{f[u], t[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, s1}]]`. Trying  to understand what the error was, I tried to compute `n[1]//N` and I noticed I obtain this:

> [image]

**Ie:** It seems Mathematica differentiates `Abs[x]` but doesn't know what to so with it later. I tried to compute `Abs'[1]` and it didn't work. Is there something I can do for this to work? Perhaps some assumption I could use where it replaces `Abs'[x]` for something Mathematica knows how to handle?

Comment: Try:`t[u_] := Simplify[Normalize[f'[u]], Assumptions -> u \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/simplifying-the-derivative-of-x, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229650/cannot-derive-norm-or-normalize-when-recreating-frenet-serret-equations

Comment: The trouble is that `Abs` is not complex differentiable, so you must insist to *Mathematica* that your domain is the reals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `Derivative[1][RealAbs][x]` work, so we can use `/. Abs -> RealAbs`

```
Graphics3D[{BSplineCurve[Table[f[u], {u, 0, 2 Pi, s}]], 
   Arrow[Table[{f[u], t[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, s1}]], 
   Arrow[Table[{f[u], n[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, s1}]]}] /. Abs -> RealAbs
```

[image]

Comment: +1 `RealAbs` was introduced in v11.1; for earlier versions for real `x`, use `Abs[x] :> Sqrt[x^2]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you! Forget the gym... that's a smart way to get real abs :)