Questions About the FunctionExpand Function
Today, while helping someone solve a problem, I encountered an issue with the Abs function in their expression. I needed to derive the Abs function and then plot it. The original image was a curve, but the plot ended up as a discontinuous straight line, which is obviously wrong. So, I started to check my code step by step and found the problem lies with the derivative of the Abs function.
Here I used the N function, but I didn't get a numerical solution. Then, in the suggestion bar below, Mathematica suggested I use FunctionExpand. I tried this function, and it indeed worked.

I'm not sure why this is the case and I'm hoping someone can help explain it to me.

This is a bug in FunctionExpand. According to the documentation to Abs "Abs is not a differentiable function".

I don't understand the explanation "Adding assumptions that the argument is real makes Abs differentiable" in the documentation. The correct formulation should be as "The restriction of Abs[z] on the real axis is  a differentiable function of  the real variable z, except z==0, and this function is denoted by RealAbs[z]".

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8188/1871

As far as I understand the documentation to FunctionExpand, here
FunctionExpand[D[Abs[x], x], Assumptions -> x > 0]


1

is used for x == 0.9510565162951535.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

As stated in the documentation, "Abs is a function of a complex variable and is therefore not differentiable." You must either use assumptions or use RealAbs. Then use PiecewiseExpand.
der[t_] = Derivative[1][RealAbs][Sin[2 Pi  t]] // PiecewiseExpand

(* Piecewise[{{-1, Sin[2*Pi*t] < 0}}, 1] *)

der[0.2]

(* 1 *)

Plot[{Abs[Sin[2 Pi  t]], der[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]


EDIT: Or using Assumptions and FullSimplify
FullSimplify[Abs'[Sin[2 Pi  t]], Assumptions -> t ∈ Reals]

(* Sign[Sin[2 π t]] *)

