# Using ArcLength in Mathematica 10 using absolute values

Tags: regions, version-10, differential-geometry

With Mathematica 10, I can nicely plot:

```
y = x^2 - 4 Abs[x] - x
```

But I have not been able to use `ArcLength` to get the length of portions of the curve.

I have an old Derive 6 math program that both plots and gets the arc length of the equation very nicely.

Why not with Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The problem is that *Mathematica* is built to assume that all variables are complex be default (for full generality), and [$|z|$ is not complex-differentiable](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-49-prev.pdf). Adding the assumption `$Assumptions = {x ∈ Reals};` might help here.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8185

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica does not know how to take the derivative of `Abs[x]`

```
D[Abs[x], x]
```

> Derivative[1][Abs][x]

Consequently, use the equivalent (for real x) `Sqrt[x^2]`

```
Abs[x] == Sqrt[x^2] // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &
```

> True

```
f[x_] = x^2 - 4 Sqrt[x^2] - x;

ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> 1/2 (5 Sqrt[26] + ArcSinh[5])

```
% // N
```

> 13.9038

Answer (score 5):

One way to get the real-number version of `Abs`, which is piecewise differentiable is to use `ComplexExpand`:

```
ArcLength[ComplexExpand@{x, x^2 - 4 Abs[x] - x}, {x, 0, 5}]
(*  1/2 (5 Sqrt[26] + ArcSinh[5])  *)
```

Alternatively, `PiecewiseExpand`, along with the assumption that `x` is real works, too:

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals,
 ArcLength[{x, PiecewiseExpand[x^2 - 4 Abs[x] - x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
 ]
(*  1/2 (5 Sqrt[26] + ArcSinh[5])  *)
```

Comment: @MichaelE2...I do not know why but I always seem to forget this! +1 :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks.  Your remark about "the consistent and problematic `Abs[x]`" makes me think there may be a duplicate.  In fact I think I once answered in terms of `Piecewise` like you did and someone else used `ComplexExpand`.  Lots of related questions - probably won't have time to sort through them all.

Answer (score 3):

Rather uninspiringly but consistent with problematic `Abs[x]`:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2 + 3 x, x < 0}, {x^2 - 5 x, x > 0}}]
```

e.g.

```
ArcLength[f[x], {x, -2, 2}]
ArcLength[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
ArcLength[f[x], {x, -2, 0}]
```

yield respectively,

```
1/4 (3 Sqrt[10] + 5 Sqrt[26] + ArcSinh[3] + ArcSinh[5])
1/4 (-Sqrt[2] + 5 Sqrt[26] - ArcSinh[1] + ArcSinh[5])
1/4 (Sqrt[2] + 3 Sqrt[10] + ArcSinh[1] + ArcSinh[3])
```

For fun:

```
Column[{Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> f[x], ImageSize -> 400],
  Plot[ArcLength[f[s], {s, -2, u}], {u, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabel -> ArcLength[f[x], {x, -2, s}], ImageSize -> 400]}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since `Abs` behaves badly in some situations, let's first assume you want the arc length for some `x>0`. When `x>0`, your function can be rewritten as (I'll keep that un-simplified form so that you see, I only removed the `Abs`)

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 4 x - x
```

Now we can calculate the arc length for the interval [0,5] [with the usual formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) manually

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1+f'[x]^2],{x,0,5}]
(* 1/2 (5 Sqrt[26]+ArcSinh[5]) *)
```

If you want to use `ArcLength`, you just have to note that you need to put it into a parametric form

```
ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 5}]
(* 1/2 (5 Sqrt[26] + ArcSinh[5]) *)
```

Comment: I appreciate the info from you guys. I continue to learn.

Comment: I made my own arc length function, AL, that seems to work well and handles the absolute values of variables. It is:

Comment: Clear[x, y, a, b];
AL[y_, x_, a_, b_] := 
 Integrate[Sqrt[1 + (D[ComplexExpand@y, x])^2], {x, a, b}]

Comment: I have now changed the above to:  Clear[x,y,a,b];
ArcL[y_, x_,a_, b_] :=
Integrate[Sqrt[1 +(D[ComplexExpand[Re[y],TargetFunctions->Abs],x])^2], {x,a,b}]