# Conversion between Piecewise[] and Abs[] representations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise, conversion

Is there a utility in *Mathematica* that can convert between two representations of an expression?
The simplest example I can think of is

```
Abs[x]
```

Which I'd like to convert to something like

```
Piecewise[{{-x,x<0},{x,x>=0}}]
```

Another simple example is

```
f[r_]:= 1/16 ((-3+6r) Abs[1 - 2 r] + (3 - 2 r) Abs[3 - 2 r] 
- 3 (1 + 2 r) Abs[1 + 2 r] + (3 + 2 r) Abs[3 + 2 r])

Assuming[r > 1/2, Simplify[f[r]]]
Assuming[-1/2 < r < 1/2, Simplify[f[r]]]
Assuming[r < -1/2, Simplify[f[r]]]
Assuming[-2 < r < 2, Simplify[f[r]]]
Assuming[-1/2 < r < 3/2, Simplify[f[r]]]
Assuming[0 < r < 2, Simplify[f[r]]]
```

which produces the output (sorry for formatting; I'm just using "copy as LaTeX" from Mathematica):

```
Out[2]=
```

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{8} (3-2 r)^2 & 2 r\leq 3 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}
$$

```
 Out[3]=
```

$$\frac{3}{4}-r^2$$

```
 Out[4]=
```

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{8} (2 r+3)^2 & r\geq -\frac{3}{2} \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}$$

```
 Out[5]=1/16 ((-3 + 6 r) Abs[1 - 2 r] + (3 - 2 r) Abs[3 - 2 r] 
 - 3 (1 + 2 r) Abs[1 + 2 r] + (3 + 2 r) Abs[3 + 2 r])

 Out[6]=
```

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{3}{4}-r^2 & 2 r\leq 1 \\
 \frac{1}{8} (3-2 r)^2 & \text{True} \\
\end{cases}
$$

```
 Out[7]=1/16 (6 - 8 r^2 + (-3 + 6 r) Abs[1 - 2 r] + (3 - 2 r) Abs[3 -2 r])
```

So it's able to recognize what the function is over each domain, and if there are only two pieces, it can produce a piecewise expression, but if there are more than two pieces it fails.  Is there another way to get piecewise expressions that would be better than `Assuming[xmin<x<xmax,Simplify[f[x]]`?

For testing purposes, the following function can be used to generate piecewise functions (not explicitly piecewise, but using `Abs[]` as above).  `g[n]` will produce an n-segment piecewise expression on the interval `[-n/2,n/2]` with segments of length 1.

```
g[n_Integer] := Assuming[-n <= r <= n, 
                Integrate[1/(2 π) (Sin[k/2]/(k/2))^n 
                (Cos[k r] - I Sin[k r]), 
                {k, -∞, ∞}]]
```

version info:

```
$Version
"11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"
```

Comment: Duplicate: [(127447)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127459).
Answer embedded in solution to other questions: [(76747)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76747), [(79246)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79246), etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `PiecewiseExpand`, with its second argument being `Reals`:

```
PiecewiseExpand[
 1/16 ((-3 + 6 r) Abs[1 - 2 r] + (3 - 2 r) Abs[3 - 2 r] - 
    3 (1 + 2 r) Abs[1 + 2 r] + (3 + 2 r) Abs[3 + 2 r]), Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]