# Getting a usable expression tree

Tags: expression-manipulation, expression-construction

I need to get the expression tree for some expression.

```
expr //TreeForm
```

The above grabs the expression tree but it isn't in some sort of usable format. Just an image.

```
Level[expr, {-1}, "Heads"->True]
```

This does a depth first traversal of the expression tree and does give me a list of all items in the expression tree. The issue with this is that:

```
expr = a+b*3*c+d
Level[expr, {-1}, "Heads"->True]
{Plus, a, Times, 3, b, c, d}
```

and now you can see that because of the location of d I have no information on what goes where with Levels.

So the question is, is there a way for me to get the expression tree in some format where I can actually tell where everything is supposed to go?

Acceptable formats would be of the form of {operator/operatorFunctionName, symbol/value, {operator/operatorFunctionName, symbol/value, {... continues as far as can go}}, moreSymbolsRelatedToFirstOperation}

OR

{operator/operatorFunctionName, operator/operatorFunctionName, ...} {{symbol/valueForFirstOperator, ...}, {symbol/valueForSecondOperator,...}, ...}

OR any other similar format.

Comment: `expr` [already *is* an expression tree.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)  What format do you want?  Is `FullForm[expr]` helpful?

Comment: I recognize that it is already an expression tree. FullForm is only somewhat helpful (because I might just have to use it to parse the expression tree). 

Ultimately I need to do these computations in Java/SQL which is why I need the expression tree.

Comment: Sorry hit enter before I finished my comment... I just edited my comment to clarify why I need the expression itself in a different format. As far as a specific format.. Some sort of list. Ideally it would be some form of binary tree. But like I said above I need to pass the expression itself into Java so that I can evaluate through SQL/Java rather than Mathematica.

Comment: People have posted clever and simple methods for getting the form you asked for, but I want to point out that J/Link's `Expr` class provides a native Java representation of arbitrary Mathematica expressions. It has methods like `head()`, `part()`, `length()`, `take()`, `integerQ()`, etc. that you can use to analyze and deconstruct the `Expr` on the Java side. Just mentioning this in case you might find it easier to pass the expression intact into Java and then walk through it with Java code.

Comment: @ToddGayley I didn't realize that I had those functions on the Java side. I could have done it on the Java side but even with my small knowledge of mathematica it was easier in this instance to finish the rest of the parsing that I needed as well as validation through a recursive function in mathematica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please let me know if this is moving in the right direction:

```
expr = a + b*3*c + d;

Replace[expr, h_[x___] :> {x}, {0, -1}]
```

> ```
> {a, {3, b, c}, d}
> ```

Given that heads are lost here, perhaps you want something like:

```
Replace[expr, h_[x___] :> {h, x}, {0, -1}]
```

> ```
> {Plus, a, {Times, 3, b, c}, d}
> ```

If this is close to what you a related question that you should read is:
[List manipulation to build a functional expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20328/121)

---

Note: you may be tempted to try to simplify the code above by using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (short form `/.`) but you will find that it doesn't work.  That's because the [order of traversal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121) is the opposite of [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html), despite the similar names.

Comment: That second one is pretty much exactly what I was wanting. Since it builds the expression itself into a list with the heads for each portion.

Comment: @harageth Great! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Very nice and clear.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this...

```
{#, Extract[expr, #]} & /@ Position[expr, _]
```

> {{{0}, Plus}, {{1}, a}, {{2, 0}, Times}, {{2, 1}, 3}, {{2, 2}, 
>     b}, {{2, 3}, c}, {{2}, 3 b c}, {{3}, d}, {{}, {}}}

**Breakdown**

`Position[expr, _]` will return all of the positions of parts of `expr`.

> {{0}, {1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2}, {3}, {}}

Now that you know where everything is, you can use that information to retrieve the elements themselves, via the initial code.

Comment: FYI: "part zero" is the head of an expression, as can be seen with `Plus` and `Times` above.

Answer (score 2):

In 12.3, [ExpressionTree](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionTree.html) can be used to produce a usable tree:

[[image: ExpressionTreea+b3c+d]