# Bare symbol invocation fails but not if used with an argument

Tags: programming, evaluation, variable-definitions, assignment

How to achieve the following behavior on a symbol f?

Background: The main goal is to use the symbol to tag an abstract data structure where downvalues are used to store information. Only defined downvalues are to be used. The bare invocation of a symbol in an expression should result in an error message.

Note: I am not asking how to design the abstract data structure. What I am asking is the following:

The context in which this symbol is to be used is something like this (a snapshot of a stack):

```
f := Fail;
f[_] := Fail;
f[1] = value1;
f[2] = value2;
```

so that only invocation on existing downvalues or when a new downvalue is defined it works, but both invocation on a non-existing downvalue fails, and the bare invocation fails. For example, assume that the stack looks like this before we start using the symbol

```
f := Fail
f[_] := Fail
```

and then we start using the f symbol like this

```
f = 3 (* fails due to f := $Fail *);
    f[1] = value1 (* works, an assignment *);
    f[2] = value2 (* ibid *);
    x = f + 1 (* fails due to f := $Fail *);
x = f[3] + 1 (* fails due to f[_] := $Fail *);
x = f[1] + 1 (* works: x = value1 + 1 *);
x = f[2] + 1 (* works: x = value2 + 1 *);
f[3] = value3 (* works: an assignemnt *); 
x = f[3] + 1 (* should now work since f[3] has been assigned *);
```

Here is an example when one actually tries to implement this

```
ClearAll[f];
f := fail1;
f[___] := fail2
```

This results in

```
Information[f]
Global`f
f:=fail1
```

which is good. We want it to fail if invoked directly without argument. However, the default invocation on non-existing downvalues is already problematic:

```
Information[fail1]
Global`fail1
fail1[___]:=fail2
```

thus something that is not wanted. (I understand why this happens: The `SetDelayed` command evaluates its LHS). Everything goes down the drain right at the beginning, since one would not be able to define the `SetDelayed` part.

Background[EDIT]: A mathematica code is being passed to a function which changes it slighlty. the code on input looks like, e.g.,

```
this@f1 = value1
this@f2 = this@f1 + 1
```

and the processed code should read

```
o@f1 = value1
o@f2 = o@f1 + 1
```

if the user specifies

```
f1 = value1
this@f2 = this@f1 + 1
```

the system should complain. I know how to do this on the phraser level, no problem. I wonder, is it possible to arrange for the suitable definitions for f1 and f2 so that the behavior I desired occurs, i.e. later on when f1 = value1 is evaluated that an exception occurs?

Also the following is defined silently at the same time

```
o[id_]@f_ := f[id]
```

In this way one can define a super simple data strcuture that can be instantiated like a class and operated upon. it should be very natural to write method definitions for such a class.

Comment: Check out `Stack`

Comment: Why do you think that there is some kind of magic that will allow you to override _Mathematica_'s semantics at such a basic level?

Comment: @m_goldberg, there is `Stack`. But most of us tend to avoid it

Comment: `SetAttributes[dvQ, HoldFirst];
dvQ[sym_] := Stack[_]~MatchQ~{___, HoldForm[_sym], _};

ClearAll[f]
f /; StackInhibit[! dvQ[f]] := fail;
f[2] = 3;
f[_] := fail;`

Comment: @Rojo. I don't think `Stack` was implemented to provide a way to subvert basic semantics and certainly would not recommend it for that purpose.

Comment: the use of Fail is meant to indicate that some sort of a failure message should be issued. apologies for confusion.  why this? I needed to do this so many times, that I finally decided to ask for help. for my problem at hand, f must be used on existing downvalues only, anything else should fail, and do it loudly (to warn the user that his/her function is defined inconsistently, no need for details). Thanks for all the constructive comments! I know this is not easy! Yes, I agree, this is not easy in Mathematica. It never checks, just does.

Comment: in retrospective, it can't be that bad wanting to do this. we often want to save data as indexable downvalues right? using bare f without "index" is a serious bug. can happen. the code should complain when this happens. anyway, my problem is different. user is providing a definition for a function that I have to modify slighlty (like a super simpler compiler) before passing it on to the interenal machinery that uses the function. (you guess correctly, it is about method definition for an object).

Comment: @zorank *Mathematica* is quite flexible but it is not amorphous.  While they *can* make for interesting exercises attempting to work against *Mathematica*'s intended behavior is usually not a wise design decision.  From your brief description of the problem I can't see a reason for you to need what you illustrate here; I think you could keep the `DownValues` definitions as a hidden back end to a more directly specifiable frond end construct.  You may also wish to consider something like ``System`Utilities`HashTable`` (search for examples) or the new `Association` in version 10, once available.

Comment: Your update reads: "A mathematica code is being passed to a function which changes it slightly." In what form is this code passed?  As an expression in `Hold`?  As a String?  Your example looks like a potentially simple application of pattern matching would solve your problem, but first I need to understand the input format.

Comment: By the way, have you seen this self-Q&A from Leonid Shifrin?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869/121

Comment: yes I have seen his post. it was a source of inspiration if not a solution I am using. however, i realized that I doing all that so often that I needed a smart phraser that would help me define classes and methods in a safe way. the input could be both I supose, at the moment it is implemented as a string, using ToString[HoldForm[input]]. this way one does not have to wory about evaluations etc when working the changes.

Comment: So you want to forbid assignments and usage of `f1` unless it's wrapped by `this`? That's more doable. You just need to make `this` set a dynamic environment that turns off the `f1` evaluation warning. Am I understanding right?

Comment: @zorank For the "the system should complain" input did you mean `this = value1` instead of `f1 = value1` as that would seem to match the rest of your question better.

Comment: I updated my answer; please take a look and let me know what may need changing.

Comment: @Rojo True! You are understanding it right. The point is that the phraser will convert it properly then. For example, this@f will be converted into o@f where o is the object defined someplace in the code, somehow.

Answer (score 4):

### General considerations

I think your goal here is misguided.  If you state what you are *actually trying to accomplish* we can probably recommend alternative approaches.

Due to the [standard evaluation sequence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20331/121) the heads of expressions are evaluated first, if `f` has a direct (OwnValues) assignment it will evaluate first in the expression `f[1]`.

*Edit:* As Rojo also notes `Fail` is a System symbol with a specific function relating to `Condition` expressions.  I shall use `$Failed` instead below.

Observe that given in the right order these definitions can be made, though they will not work as you desire:

```
f[_] := $Failed;
f[1] = value1;
f[2] = value2;
f := $Failed;

OwnValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f] :> $Failed}
> ```

```
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> value1,
>  HoldPattern[f[2]] :> value2,
>  HoldPattern[f[_]] :> $Failed}
> ```

But now:

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> $Failed[1]
> ```

As Rojo commented you may be able to use [`Stack`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Stack.html) to circumvent this, as Leonid did for [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121) but first I think you should consider alternative approaches.  Again, *why* do you want to do this?

I think work noting: even if `f` evaluates to `$Failed` it can still have its value reassigned with `Set`:

```
f = foo;

f[2]
```

> ```
> foo[2]
> ```

I take from your example that you wish to prevent this.  Is that the primary motivation of your question?

---

### A possible specific solution

Guessing a bit as to what you need I think this may be moving in the right direction.
Here are two sample inputs, changed from your example to what I *think* you might have meant:

```
in1 = "this@f1 = value1
  this@f2 = this@f1 + 1";

in2 = "this = value1
  this@f2 = this@f1 + 1";
```

Now the `process` function:

```
process[in_String] :=
 If[FreeQ[#, HoldPattern[this]], #, $Failed] &[
  ToHeldExpression[in] /. HoldPattern[this[x_]] :> o[x]
 ]
```

And example applications:

```
process @ in1
process @ in2
```

> ```
> Hold[o[f1] = value1, o[f2] = o[f1] + 1]
>
> $Failed
> ```

Comment: Mhm, was just about to write that definitions can be made in another order, but when I tried it out `fail1`:=)

Comment: Given that you are giving high level recommendations, I would add to avoid `Fail` unless you know what to expect

Comment: @Rojo I don't know (or recall) what `Fail` is used for, so other than the normal recommendation of avoiding user Symbols starting with a capital letter I fear I miss your implication.

Comment: `Fail` if returned by a rhs condition means "the condition didn't match".

Comment: Check `ga[] := Block[{}, Fail /; True];
go[] := Block[{}, $Failed /; True];
{ga[], go[]}`

Comment: @Rojo Wow, I didn't know that.  Still so much to learn.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: It's what `RuleCondition` returns when its 2nd (and other) arguments aren't all `True`. I don't think any of this is worth mentioning in this answer, but a warning to avoid `Fail` seems appropriate

Comment: please see the comments above for a hint of what I am trying to acomplish. but that is not important. I am really curous how to do what I ask. it happens so often (at least to me) that I want that kind of control.

Comment: what I would like is to know how to construct a symbol that behaves like I specified in the "f = 3 ... x = f[3] + 1" block. that's all.

Comment: @zorank Well now you are beginning to see the problem with working against *Mathematica* semantics.  Frequently there *is* a way to force what you want but it comes at a cost of fragility, overhead, or makes your code unportable.  However, depending on your usage you may find use in `UpSet` and `TagSet`; please look at those, and ask for help as needed.

Comment: please see the EDIT in the first post for additional information.

Comment: hmmmm, this seems so compliated that by implementing such behavior, one can create another more subtle bugs. what I am actually asking, implicitly, is that the rule (that modifies f) should know something about the context from which it was invoked, and that looks like the mission impossible. for example, oh yes, I was invoked with an argument, does the argument exists, yes, fine, there you go, or, humps I was invoked but without an argument, throw and exception... Rojo's trick is to capture the broader invocation environment, isn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I am aware of these, but have no clue how these could help me. of course, I will rethink very carefully what you suggested though a hint on how to use TagSet and UpSet to solve the present problem would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: Ohhh, I see, he meant that the checking would be done in the o@f construct. but that does not solve the problem of directly using f in the code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "A possible specific solution" is the solution. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! However, there is an additional catch. One can use this@f (an operation on the field) or this@method[args] (invoking a function on the object). The process function would never know what it might get. Is there a way to accomodate for this second option?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After a bit of mediation I think I understand your code. It replaces this@f into o@f and makes sure that all "this" symbols have been cleared, and all that in one line. Amazing! To make this really work, I would need a list of symbols that are absolutely forbidden to occur on their own (i.e. that need to be wrapped into this@... construct). I supose one could do substitutions twice, once with this@f_Symbol :> o@f (variable/field/attribute invocation), and once with this@method_[args___]:>o@method[args] (method invocation). But, how to enforce something like this@f :> (check[f];o@f)?

Comment: @zorank I'm just passing by for a minute.  Re: your first question, yes, `this@method[args]` can almost certainly be handled as you want, but I need to know what it is to be transformed into.  Re: the second question, I'm not sure I understand the "substitutions twice" idea.  If you update your question with a more complete series of input-ouput mappings I can try to craft a series of rules that do what you wish.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (1a) this@f1 :> o@f1, (2) this@f2 :> o@f2, etc if f1, f2, ... are members of some pre-defined list, e.g. allowedFs = {f1, f2, ...}; (1b) this@g should be detected as error (assuming that g does not belong to the pre-defined list); (3) this@method_[args___] :> o@method[args] (here we do not check whether method belongs to some list); (4) if f1 or any of other members in the allowed list occurs on its own e.g. "...; this@f2 = f1 + 1; ..." then the alone f1 should be detected as an error and the processing function should complain loudly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this dilema seems to be that these sort of checks have to be done in the phraser that processes the code. Only there is the information sitting how the symbol is to be used.

However, as it concerns the original question, a half way solution is like this:

```
ClearAll[f]
f /: Set[f, rhs___] := Print["fail1: ", ToString@rhs]
f /: SetDelayed[f, rhs___] := Print["fail2: ", ToString@rhs]
f[arg___] := Print["fail3: ", ToString@arg]

?f
Global`f
(f=rhs___)^:=Print[fail1: ,ToString[rhs]]
(f:=rhs___)^:=Print[fail2: ,ToString[rhs]]
f[arg___]:=Print[fail3: ,ToString[arg]]

runCode := 
 (
  Print["In (should fail): f=3"]; f = 3 (*fails with fail1 *);
  Print["In: f[1]=value1"]; f[1] = value1 (*works,an assignment*);
  Print["In: f[2]=value2"]; f[2] = value2 (*ibid*);
  Print["In (should fail but does not): x=f+1"]; x = f + 1 (*?fails with?*);
  Print["In (should fail): x=f[3]+1"]; x = f[3] + 1 (*fails with fail3 *);
  Print["In: x=f[1]+1"]; x = f[1] + 1 (*works:x=value1+1*);
  Print["In: x=f[2]+1"]; x = f[2] + 1 (*works:x=value2+1*);
  Print["In: f[3]=value3"]; f[3] = value3 (*works:an assignemnt*);
  Print["In: x=f[3]+1"]; x = f[3] + 1 (*should now work since f[
  3] has been assigned*);
  )
```

now we test it

```
runCode    
In (should fail): f=3
fail1: 3

In: f[1]=value1

In: f[2]=value2

In (should fail but does not): x=f+1

In (should fail): x=f[3]+1   
fail3: 3

In: x=f[1]+1

In: x=f[2]+1

In: f[3]=value3

In: x=f[3]+1
```

Almost, almost... The only problem is the "In (should fail but does not): x=f+1
" piece, when the symbol is used without an argument. For example, the following does not work ("TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag f not found in lhs_:=rhs_")

```
f /: SetDelayed[lhs_, rhs_] := (lhs := rhs) /; 
  failIfRhsIsNotOK[rhs, f]
```

nor ("TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag f in lhs_:=rhs_/;failIfRhsIsNotOo[rhs,f] is too deep for an assigned rule to be found. ")

```
f /: SetDelayed[lhs_, 
  rhs_ /; failIfRhsIsNotOK[rhs, f]] := (lhs := rhs)
```

nor ("ibid")

```
f /: SetDelayed[lhs_, rhs_?failIfRhsIsNotOK[rhs, f]] := (lhs := rhs)
```

In fact, even a simple construct like this

```
f /: Set[lhs_, rhs : Plus[_, f]] := (lhs = rhs)
```

does not work ("TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag f in lhs_=rhs:f+_ is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.")

Anyway, seems this is the best one can do without reworking how Mathematica deals with expressions on the basic level.

Regards
Zoran