# Shorthand for operations?

Tags: functions, operators

Mathematica has a large number of built-in symbols, and I am unsure when there is a shorthand for the operation I am trying to perform.

**Question 1:**

Is there a shorthand for the function `Join[#,#] &`? Here I only need the operation to apply to lists.

**Question 2:**

Is there a shorthand for a function which swaps out one operation with another:

```
f[bool_, a_, b_] := If[bool, a + b, a - b]
```

Comment: I highly recommend waiting 24 hours before Accepting an answer, to give people all around the world time to respond.  You never know what answers you might get. :-)

Comment: Point taken. Unaccepted for now.

Comment: I guess no one else feels like answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of a way to improve `Join[#, #] &`.  Merely as a game you could use:

```
{##, ##} & @@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
> ```

However this is inadvisable because it will unpack packed arrays and it loses the original Head.

For the second case if the arguments are long, rather than just `a` and `b`, it can be shorter to use:

```
If[bool, Plus, Subtract][a, b]
```

Somewhat related: [List manipulation to build a functional expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20328/121).

You could also use two separate definitions:

```
f[True,  a_, b_] := a + b
f[False, a_, b_] := a - b
```

Neither is an improvement in your example but each has its place I believe.

Comment: Thanks, the `If[bool, Plus, Subtract]` was what I was looking for. I am embarrassed to admit that I had tried `If[bool, +, -]` before giving up.

Comment: @pre-kidney You're welcome.  We all have mental blocks from time to time; I think I have more than my share of them.