# Mathematica Application in Real Life

Tags: programming

As an 'user'-level in *Mathematica*, I mainly use built-in *Mathematica* function and benefit *Mathematica* as a mathematical tool-box for my specific scientific problem. My level is not yet programmer-level.

The magic of *Mathematica* is that there are endless level of skill to improve. It is hardly to evaluate a C-programmer by viewing his code. But for *Mathematica*, be viewing the code, the level could be evaluated. Normally, when skilled level increases, the length of code decreases. Based on the idea of Leonid Shifrin and the level in online game, I myself auto evaluate my skill.

- Level 0 - Level 20: Beginner-Users who uses mainly built-in functions.
- Level 20 - Level 40: Intermediate, mix some long       procedural    programming and functional style
- Level 40 - Level 60:    Expert, low-level system understanding

Although I have "*Mathematica* ***Advanced*** Foundation Level" certification, I think my level is Beginner - Pre-Intermediate about level 18- to level 22. I can not understand the Expert level, for example [One-Line Code Competition](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/01/the-2011-mathematica-one-liner-competition/). As we can see here, Expert level codes program in just 'one line'. :)

My question is, could you please introduce the use of Mathematica as a real-life application? It is not a question of technique, but a question of idea, imagination. Your applications could open my eye of the use of Mathematica in your real-life. I also see "User Stories" on *Wolfram* site, but almost of them are scientific, industrial applications.

In my case, as an researcher-lecturer at University, I intend to use Mathematica in my teaching. Correct the copies take me a lot of time. So my project is:

- Use *Mathematica* to auto generate MCQ (Multiple Choice Question) question based on my question data base.
- Scan students answers as an image file.
- Use *Mathematica* to generate the note by image manipulating on these scanned copies. (The optical reader in my university is really expensive, and not available for everyone). So coding my own *Mathematica* code is optimal way.

Ideas, projects of the use of *Mathematica* in real life are welcome !

Comment: `projects of the use of Mathematica in real life are welcome` one example is http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @Nasser O my! [Now I understand](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GejUA.png)

Comment: Personally, I think this is a good question, especially as it's more likely to arise in the future from newcomers to the "Wolfram Language". However, be warned that questions without any objectively correct answer are generally frowned upon in the StackExchange format.

Comment: So you're looking for non-scientific examples of the use of Mathematica in people's "daily life"? There are plenty of examples on this and other sites. But I don't see where your "expert levels" and code brevity concerns come in to the question...?

Comment: This question is pretty clearly [out of scope](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) by way of being open ended.  Nevertheless I find it an interesting question so for the time being I shall leave it open.  I have converted it to a "community wiki" which has been serving as a de facto "gray area" for such topics.

Comment: There is something in this question. I once again realise I think a good voting system on this site is very important. `level == reputation`, or `level == reputation/numberOfAnswers` can sound appealing. I imagine improvements to the voting system should be possible.

Comment: Also: @Mr.Wizard and Leonid should give out silly certificates that you can print out and show to your relatives :P.

Comment: Regarding understanding of those one-liners, I'm fairly certain nobody really knows why they do what they do, not even their authors. It's probably a matter of playing with /@ vs @@ vs @@@, Through/Thread/Map/MapThread, Fold/Nest, then maybe Flatten to taste. That at least is my opinion. I've never in my life come close to writing an actual competitive Mathematica one-liner, so my view could be jaundiced..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This answer is entirely opinion, but given the question, what else could it be?

I reject the OP's linear skill rating proposal. *Mathematica* is too large and to amorphous for the skill of its diverse user community to be categorized in such a tidy way.

I also disagree with the OP's view that code will inevitably get more concise as one's *Mathematica* skills increase. One does get better at playing code golf, but for serious projects -- say writing a *Mathematica* package intended to be used by many people over many years -- the need to support argument validation,  manage options, supply meaningful error and usage messages, support unit and functional-level testing, etc., all conspire to bloat the code far above the conciseness that can be achieved when one doesn't need to worry about such things, such as when answering questions of this site. That is, for many "real-life applications", the need to do software engineering overrides the aesthetics of concise coding.

Comment: I would vote for this twice if I could. All too often here on SE we put an unduly (IMO) strong emphasis on concise code, and I have to say that for real-life (or, just larger) Mathematica projects, at least in my experience, more often than not the main difficulty is elsewhere - the right design, managing code infrastructure, splitting it up into right modules, maintaining testability, etc - basically all things you have described.

Comment: One thing that I would add to this is that one direction to reduce the code bloating which seems to be currently severely underused is meta-programming, which is capable of separating the concerns (e.g. error-checking and main code logic), etc. One reason for this seems to be that, in order to be used effectively by many users, this has to be packaged in some kind of a framework. And frameworks are hard to get right and even harder to win a widespread adoption, if they are not the end products but some middleware software tools.

Comment: @Leonid meta-programming has been your baby for some time now; perhaps you could move toward official framework support in v10/11/+?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not the only one in the company to use it, by far. Besides, for this particular topic (and some others as well), I would prefer an open-source development. So yes, I'd like to do this. The problem is to find the time, as always. I do have some plan for this, so let's see.

Comment: @Leonid You laid out a wonderful [summary](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2352/121) of the topic and I appreciate that.  Have you now observed methods that are different from or extend beyond the concepts presented there?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have not had much time for further explorations, during the time that passed since that post (yes, I know this may sound strange given that it has been almost two years, but that's true). I am sure there are methods yet to be discovered and / or clarified. Some of the methods (such as macros) are made prohibitively hard to use by the complex evaluation semantics of Mathematica, and require additional infrastructure to be used more widely. Such infrastructure can be constructed within Mathematica itself, but this again requires time.

Answer (score 11):

A real life application... **Decision Maker** is one of the most useful Mathematica programs I have ever written. It came about because it was a cold and rainy day: I didn't feel like riding my bike home from work, taking the bus would take a long time, and it would be humiliating to ask for a ride. What to do? I couldn't decide, but **Decision Maker** could:

```
RandomChoice[{"ride bike", "take bus", "find ride"}]
```

I have often found myself using different versions of this program when I need help with decisions. I think this makes me (about) a level -5 user.

Comment: Funny answer ! I never used MM like this yet !

Comment: Wished I would have seen this sooner, really helps in my day to day decisions +1.

Comment: Which reminds me of [*Dice Man* by Luke Rhinehart](https://books.google.de/books?id=gXQjCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dice+man&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=dice%20man&f=false). :)