# What are some "real-world" applications of Mathematica?

Tags: application

I have a theory, which I am in the process of writing about in a blog post, that other than in applications in mathematics (symbolic logic), Mathematica's primary usefulness is in encouraging a kind of intellectual dilettantism. (Of course, one man's dilettantism is another man's New Kind of Science: i.e. the speculative endeavors of a fertile, creative intellect might readily be mistaken for actual (scientific) achievement by less agile minds.)
I don't want this conjecture to be true: I'm as much a buyer of the hype around Mathematica as the next man.  But I have noticed that, in practice, Mathematica somehow fails to live up to its apparently unlimited potential for encapsulating creative thought-product across an almost unlimited span of human intellectual endeavor. In my own work in finance, for instance, it has generally proved much less useful than other products such as Matlab.  And, in general, when I look at the examples cited by Wolfram in its "customer stories", my reaction to many of them is: "Sure, you can use Mathematica to do that.  But why would you, when there are much better alternatives available?".  To take one such customer story from the field of 3D CAD, I don't understand why anyone would *prefer* to use Mathematica for such a task, rather than a specialist product like Solidworks.

I am aware of applications where the use of Mathematica is fully justified. In my own work, I have used Mathematica to price complex derivatives products, a field in which it excels.  Likewise, I am somewhat familiar with Phil Zecker's work at EQA Partners, where he produced an outstanding risk management solution using Mathematica.  In both these cases, however, there is no standard, specialized alternative offering in the field of risk management, as there are, for example, in  engineering, CAD, or music. In these areas, it seems to me, Mathematica is like a Swiss Army Knife:  sure you can use it to dabble in almost anything; but I have screwdrivers, knives and corkscrews that do a better job for their specific purpose.

In any event I am looking for counter-examples of real-world applications to refute my hypothesis about Mathematica. By "real-world" I mean specifically applications in which:

(i) money changed hands (e.g. a commercial product was sold, or consulting fee earned) ; and

(ii) an alternative solution was considered and Mathematica preferred for specific reasons ("it was the only software we could afford or that was available to tackle the job", is not a valid reason to qualify the application as real-world, according to this definition)

Comment: Wolfram alpha is a real world application written in Mathematica: `The secret weapon that has allowed us, and no one else, to assemble such a vast library of algorithms, in such a diverse range of fields, is Mathematica.` from [the-secret-behind-the-computational-engine-in-wolframalpha](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2009/05/01/the-secret-behind-the-computational-engine-in-wolframalpha/) also half of Mathematica itself is written using Mathematica. I think about 50% is C/C++ and the other half is in Mathematica. This might have changed in recent versions. I remember reading this sometime ago.

Comment: Personally I do not think this post is appropriate for StackExchange because in reality it is a discussion starter, not a clearly answerable question.  I suggest you post it on Wolfram Community which encourages discussion.  The last part, which is technically phrased as a question, implicitly assumes that Mathematica is usually applied in a certain way, which is simply not the case in reality.  I could, and would like to, comment on this, but such discussions just don't fit well in a Q/A framework.

Comment: I agree with Szabolcs. It seems to me like this isn't really an appropriate question for this StackExchange community.

Comment: Related question has answers here [mathematica-application-in-real-life](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39244/mathematica-application-in-real-life)

Comment: @Szabolcs I disagree - it is a clearly answerable question: any example(s) that meet the very specific criteria given for a "real-world" applicable will suffice.  One such answer given here is Wolfram Alpha (although I wonder about its qualification re point (ii)).

Comment: Before voting to close I considered writing an answer, which made me realize that it is almost impossible to avoid turning this into a discussion.  The implicit statement of this post is that in order to refute your conjecture we must find examples satisfying the very specific and narrow criteria of (i) and (ii). I believe that is wrong because this sort of goal-oriented commercial application is not what Mathematica is meant for or used for.  The question is an interesting one and a good answer can't leave this point without comment.  Of course I might be wrong, we come from very different...

Comment: ... backgrounds and see these things differently. I am a researcher and use Mathematica daily. I think it makes my work easier and I prefer it over the alternatives. I don't know much about the world of companies.  If you do post on Wolfram Community, please post a link here and let us know.

Comment: [Beating the Averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html) is very relevant in my opinion, even though it talks about Lisp instead of Mathematica.

Comment: "Mathematica somehow fails to live up to its apparently unlimited potential for encapsulating creative thought-product across an almost unlimited span of human intellectual endeavor"--this can be explained as the result of unrealistic expectations, to put it mildly. My use of *Mathematica* is akin to that of MATLAB, which while more common, I would hardly consider nicer/better. I agree with you about SolidWorks etc. *Mathematica* is used more in research than commercially, as far as I can tell. Your "a kind of intellectual dilettantism" seems no better defined than "a new kind of science". :)

Comment: I do agree with @Szabolcs that this is a discussion (not a directly answerable question, unless one wishes to make it so narrow as to be uninteresting) better had on the Wolfram Community. This is in no way an indictment of you or your question, but just as one has to choose the product, it is important to choose the venue correctly as well. I am sure the same question will get a good response in the Community, but here, it is too difficult to address it well.

Comment: I love this phrasing: _"Mathematica's primary usefulness is in encouraging a kind of intellectual dilettantism."_ — doesn't really say much specific, but sounds fancy and is somewhat accurate from a certain point of view. I'm going to steal it for use in conversations :P Coming to the closure: I agree with the comments above that answering this is rather difficult due to the restrictions placed in (i) and (ii). I'm personally curious about what people have to say about this and probably might have thrown in a reopen vote, but I won't do so now since my vote will override everyone else's.

Comment: As for examples, [Optica](http://www.opticasoftware.com) (which is a _Mathematica_ package that is as expensive as _Mathematica_ itself) comes to mind. Also checkout [Emerald Cloud Lab](http://emeraldcloudlab.com) where their entire workflow was built in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Only last month I was at a conference where the ANZ bank (market cap 73 billion) told us how they were using Mathematica (CDF) throughout the organisation, at all levels, for daily internal reporting. Same conference a state road traffic authority had chosen it for monitoring/modelling traffic flows. ...and so on

Comment: There is a a country where the central bank implemented its visualization solution using Mathematica, and another where the insurance regulator is using CDF-based solutions for all its analytics and reporting.

Comment: Here's the link to the post on Wolfram Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/774416?p_p_auth=EKRM58jK

Comment: @R.M. Also curious. I think this question is important. It can always be closed again / blocked / protected later, if things start to get out of hand. Voting for reopening.

Comment: This is a very interesting, albeit a little loaded, question, and I have voted to reopen it. To me, coming from management consulting and business, the best reply would be, that by the criteria of the question maybe nobody in business (and even) finance should be using *Excel* these days. And yet, it still is a *lingua franca* that gets abused to do things *Mathematica* would easily surpass it. I totally believe that for management consulting (and OR/MS) it is a god's end. *Proprietarity*, unusual *syntax*, *STEM*-only focus have maybe forfeited MMA becoming the better Excel?

Comment: Sorry, I have just seen the lengthy discussion on Wolfram Community and that is great, so probably no need to fit this into this format here, while I still believe the question to be rather important.