# Setting local variables with another function

Tags: scoping

I'm working on a package with a lot of functions using Module, which all begin by unpacking the arguments into local variables.  I'd like to store this unpacking code in a separate function called Setup and just call it in each function, but the local variables don't make it out.

A simple example:

```
Setup := (z = x^2);

g[x_] := Module[{z},
Setup;
Return[z]
];

g[3]
```

returns `z$2599` when I'd like it to return `9`.  My real Setup is much longer of course, which is why I'd rather recycle it than rewrite it in each function.

Is there an easy way to make this work?

**Update: A less minimal example**

Here's a slightly less minimal example that captures more of the real situation.  In my real problem, the `Setup` code is about a page long.  At this point, I'm too far into this to change how I store the `z[i]` to a list!

```
Setup := (
numX = Length[x];
Do[z[i] = StringLength[x[[i]]], {i, numX}]
)

g[x_List] := Module[{numX, z},
Setup;
Table[z[i], {i, numX}]
]
```

`g[{"hi", "there"}]` should return `{2,5}`.

Comment: Please,can you clarify the question ? What's wrong with something like:
`setup[param_(*if required*),x_]:=x^2;
g[x_]:=Module[{ret,z},
z=setup[param,x];
ret=f[z](*if required*);
Return[ret]
];`
g[3]

Comment: You're scratching your left ear with your right hand (Spanish saying)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, interestingly, there is the same saying in Russian.

Comment: @garej I guess that's because of the gauge invariance of the human body :)

Comment: @Szabolcs Out of curiosity, why shouldn't you use `Return` at the end of a `Module`?  Even though unnecessary, it helps me easily spot what's being returned at the end of a long `Module`.

Comment: @ChrisK Well, I shouldn't have said "shoulnd't" and I'll retract it ... I won't have any bad effects other than a (tiny) performance hit.  Some beginners always put it there because they don't understand that it is not necessary, but you are not a beginner.  If it makes the code more readable to you then use it.

Comment: Should work if you use `Block` instead of `Module`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to do is pass the parameters to `setUp` and make that function hold its arguments.

```
SetAttributes[setUp, HoldAll]
setup[z_, numX_, x_] := (numX = Length[x];
  Do[z[i] = StringLength[x[[i]]], {i, numX}])

g[x_List] := Module[{numX, z},
  setup[z, numX, x];
  Table[z[i], {i, numX}]]

g[{"hi", "there"}]

(* Out[1016]= {2, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a function for it?

```
setup[x_, y_] := {x^2 - y, y*x^3}
f[args___] := 
    Module[{u,v},
        {u,v} = setup[args];
        u + v
    ]
```

I showed this to prove that the code can be concise but I would write out the arguments of `f` explicitly as `f[x_, y_]` instead of `f[args___]` to restrict the forms that match.

Comment: The real Setup is more complicated and involves setting an a priori unknown number of local variables using DownValues (i.e. setting `z[1]`, `z[2]`, ... ).

Comment: @ChrisK It sounds like you should update the question and explain the use case better (and also motivate why you need DownValues instead of an array).

Comment: @ChrisK It is possible to splice that piece of code (`Setup`) directly into the definition of `g`, but that is an error-prone advanced operation that should really be used only as a last resort ... The topic is covered in some detail [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2335/12). I would not go that route unless I am really really sure that there is no better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the leads.  At this point I've got too much code to change how I store the processed values.

Comment: @ChrisK How about something like this (untested)? http://pastebin.com/dVx0p2ph

Comment: That works fine on my less minimal example.  I'll try it on my real problem & report back.

Comment: Works great on my real problem too and makes it much cleaner to look at.  If you submit this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @ChrisK I'll submit tomorrow! :)