# How can I make the output of Reduce more readable (with a tree)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, visualization, trees

Oftentimes, the output of `Reduce` is quite difficult to read because it has too many `&&` and `||` included in it.

For example the output of `Reduce[expr]//Simplify` for a particular `expr` I had was:

```
(ϵc == 
0 && ((ex == 0 && 
   ey == 0 && (ez ϵb != 
      0 || (ez != 0 && ϵb == 0))) || (ey != 
    0 && ϵb != 
    0 && (nr == Sqrt[ey ϵa + ex ϵb]/Sqrt[ey] || 
     nr + Sqrt[ey ϵa + ex ϵb]/Sqrt[ey] == 
      0) && (ex - I ey == 0 || ex + I ey == 0)) || (ez != 
    0 && ϵb == 
    0 && (nr == Sqrt[ϵa] || 
     nr + Sqrt[ϵa] == 0)))) || (ez == 
0 && ((ϵb == 
    0 && (nr == Sqrt[ϵa] || 
     nr + Sqrt[ϵa] == 0) && (ex != 0 || 
     ey != 0)) || (ey != 0 && ϵb != 
    0 && (nr == Sqrt[ey ϵa + ex ϵb]/Sqrt[ey] || 
     nr + Sqrt[ey ϵa + ex ϵb]/Sqrt[ey] == 
      0) && (ex - I ey == 0 || ex + I ey == 0))))
```

I was thinking it would be easier to read this if it were displayed as a tree.
However `TreeForm[%]` returns:
[image: Messy Tree] which is not much better.

Annother question suggested [truncating the tree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/truncate-treeform-to-show-only-the-top), in which case you get:
[image]

Also not great.

What I would like is to split up the tree by logic symbols, but to have the leaves of the tree be the individual equations.

### How can I get the tree to terminate at equations?

As in I'd want expressions that look like `nr == Sqrt[ea]` to be connected in a tree of `And`s and `Or`s.
It's difficult because the number of levels may be different for different parts of the tree.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of  new functionalities for [manipulating and styling trees](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Trees.html) in v13 (some of them present already in v12.3).

For example:

```
exprTree[expr_] := 
 RulesTree[
  TreeRules[ExpressionTree[expr]] /. (e : (Except[And | Or] -> __)) :>
     TreeExpression[RulesTree[e]], 
  TreeLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}, 
  TreeElementStyle -> {TreeCases[And] -> LightRed, 
    TreeCases[Or] -> LightBlue, TreeCases[_Equal] -> LightGreen, 
    TreeCases[_Unequal] -> LightYellow}, AspectRatio -> 1]

exprTree[expr]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
expr//.{eq_Equal:>ToString[eq,StandardForm],neq_Unequal:>ToString[neq,StandardForm]}
```

[image]

---

@Domen has provided an answer based on tree manipulation. Here my idea is to "atomize" the equations. Besides the `ToString` method, we can also atomize the equations with some undocumented functions.

```
c_wrap /; System`Private`HoldNotValidQ[c] := (
    System`Private`HoldSetValid[c];
    System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry[c]
);

get[wrap[data_]]:=
    data;

wrap/:MakeBoxes[c_wrap,format_]:=
    With[{data=get[c]},MakeBoxes[data,format]];
```

```
expr/.{eq:_Equal|_Unequal:>wrap[eq]}//ExpressionTree
```

[image]

This method does not work for `TreeForm` comparing with `ToString` since my format definition `wrap/:...` does not handle tree forms.